# Python: list comprehension, do f(x) if x exists?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I do something like the following in Python?

```
row = [unicode(x.strip()) if x for x in row]
```

Basically, a list comprehension where you carry out a function if the variable exists.

Thanks!

Comment: You say, if the variable exists, but I think you mean, if it is not None. The "for x in row" bit will walk through all of the "variables" in row.

Comment: Also, if you want to check for `None`, use `x is not None`.

Comment: I think this question very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/python-if-else-in-list-comprehension should not re-post the same question twice

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "if" goes at the end"

```
row = [unicode(x.strip()) for x in row if x]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. As @delnan comments above, what I really need is 'x is not None' - though that's my fault for an ambiguous explanation.

Answer (score 3):

So close.

```
row = [unicode(x.strip()) for x in row if x]
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the goals, but this should work

```
row = [unicode(x.strip()) for x in row if x ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're were thinking of the *ternary operator* syntax as used if you want if/else, e.g.:

```
row = [unicode(x.strip()) if x is not None else '' for x in row ]
```

or whatever you'd want to do.