# if/else in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How do I convert the following `for`-loop containing an `if`/`else` into a list comprehension?

```
results = []
for x in xs:
    results.append(f(x) if x is not None else '')
```

It should yield `''` if `x` is `None`, and otherwise `f(x)`.
I tried:

```
[f(x) for x in xs if x is not None else '']
```

but it gives a `SyntaxError`. What is the correct syntax?

---

<sub>See [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/) for info on `... if ... else ...`.</sub>
<sub>See [List comprehension with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442091) for *omitting* values based on a condition: `[... for x in xs if x cond]`.</sub>
<sub>See [`elif` in list comprehension conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987483) for `elif`.</sub>

Comment: The way the question is written, I'd argue that the correct answer would be `[f(x if x is not None else '') for x in xs]`.

Answer (score 2814, accepted):

You can totally do that. It's just an ordering issue:

```
[f(x) if x is not None else '' for x in xs]
```

In general,

```
[f(x) if condition else g(x) for x in sequence]
```

And, for list comprehensions with `if` conditions only,

```
[f(x) for x in sequence if condition]
```

Note that this actually uses a different language construct, a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), which itself is not part of the [comprehension syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries), while the `if` after the `for…in` is part of list comprehensions and used to *filter* elements from the source iterable.

---

Conditional expressions can be used in all kinds of situations where you want to choose between two expression values based on some condition. This does the same as the [ternary operator `?:` that exists in other languages](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator). For example:

```
value = 123
print(value, 'is', 'even' if value % 2 == 0 else 'odd')
```

Comment: That's why I prefer to put the ternary operator in brackets, it makes it clearer that it's just a normal expression, not a comprehension.

Comment: So the trick is "In list compression I write if before for then I have to add else part too". because if my `l = [ 2, 3, 4, 5]` then `[x if x % 2 == 0 for x in l]` give me error whereas `[x if x % 2 == 0 else 200 for x in l]` works.  Yes I know to filter it I should write `[ x for x in l if x % 2 == 0]`. Sorry for botheration. Thanks for your  answer.

Comment: The [python docs mention the ternary operator](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator). Note that it requires the else, or it doesn't work.

Comment: So, the answer uses a condition expression with in a list comprehension... Is that correct? Or, can we not call it a list comprehension any more?

Comment: @Phani Yes, it’s still a list comprehension, just with a conditional in its expression.

Comment: There is a distinction between the two syntaxes:

`[final-expr for x in start-expr if cond-expr]` is short for "include the result of `final-expr` for every element in `start-expr`, as long as the `cond-expr` is true in the context of this element. It just so happens that both expressions can also make use of the ternary operator. Just keep in mind that the "if" in the comprehension has the ability of *filtering* out results, i.e. ending up with fewer elements than in `start-expr`. This is not the case with an `expr1 if cond else expr2` ternary expression.

Comment: An example: `[x for x in range(50) if (x%3)==0]` will return a list of integers divisible by 3. `[x if (x%3)==0 for x in range(50)]` is invalid, as `x if (x%3)==0` is not a valid expression. @Grijesh, here is a counter-example to your rule (if before/after for): `[x for x in range(50) if ((x%3)==0 if x>20 else False)]`. This comprehension's filter criterion will only match integers that are both divisible by three and greater than 20.

Comment: How about if I wanted to break the loop based on a value, when i tried the if with break in the else it does not work. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @Drewdin List comprehensions don’t support breaking during its iteration. You will have to use a normal loop then.

Comment: @MohammedShareefC It is a _[conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)_ used in a list comprehension. A _conditional expression_ in Python is [equivalent to a _ternary operator_](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator) in C.

Comment: Can you explain this error matrix=[[1,2,32],[43,4],3,7,[8]] x=[nextsublist for sublist in matrix if type(sublist) is list else nextsublist for nextsublist in sublist ] print(x)

Comment: @SunilChaudhary The for … in … if` in list comprehensions does not support an `else`. It is only a filter for elements but does not allow choosing something else. For that, you will need the first syntax where you have the `if…else` as part of the element. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/216074) if you want to flatten a list of irregular lists.

Comment: Is it correct if we write `[f(x) for x in sequence if condition else f(x)]` ?

Comment: @WeiShanLee No, if you need an `else`, you will have to use the other syntax: `[f(x) if condition else g(x) for x in sequence]`.

Comment: Loved this answer

Comment: I use this general structure: (1) [ <val_if_true> <if condition> else <val_if_false> <for element in list> ] ;;;;;; or (2) [ <expression> <for element in list> <if condition> ];;;;; Example of (1) # To search for membership in a list ----------> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
search_string = 'b'
result = [1 if e == search_string else 0 for e in my_list]
print('found' if sum(result) > 0 else 'not found')
Example for (2) rand_nums = [1,2,3,4]
doubled_rand_nums = [k for k in rand_nums if k%2 == 0]

Answer (score 126):

Let's use this question to review some concepts. I think it's good to first see the fundamentals so you can extrapolate to different cases.

Other answers provide the specific answer to your question. I'll first give some general context and then I'll answer the question.

## Fundamentals

`if/else` statements in list comprehensions involve two things:

- List comprehensions
- Conditional expressions (Ternary operators)

### 1. List comprehensions

They [provide](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) a concise way to create lists.

Its structure consists of: "*brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses*".

#### Case 1

Here we have no condition. Each item from the iterable is added to `new_list`.

```
new_list = [expression for item in iterable]
new_list = [x for x in range(1, 10)]
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

#### Case 2

Here we have one condition.

**Example 1**

Condition: only *even* numbers will be added to `new_list`.

```
new_list = [expression for item in iterable if condition == True]
new_list = [x for x in range(1, 10) if x % 2 == 0]
> [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

**Example 2**

Condition: only *even* numbers that are multiple of 3 will be added to `new_list`.

```
new_list = [expression for item in iterable if condition == True]
new_list = [x for x in range(1, 10) if x % 2 == 0 if x % 3 == 0]
> [6]
```

But howcome we have one condition if we use two `if` in `new_list`?

The prior expression could be written as:

```
new_list = [x for x in range(1, 10) if x % 2 and x % 3 == 0]
> [6]
```

We only use one `if` statement.

This is like doing:

```
new_list = []
for x in range(1, 10):
    if x % 2 == 0 and x % 3 == 0:
        new_list.append(x)
> [6]
```

**Example 3**

Just for the sake of argument, you can also use `or`.

Condition: *even* numbers or numbers multiple of 3 will be added to `new_list`.

```
new_list = [x for x in range(1, 10) if x % 2 == 0 or x % 3 == 0]
> [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

#### Case 3

More than one condition:

Here we need the help of conditional expressions (Ternary operators).

### 2.Conditional Expressions

What are conditional expressions? What the name says: a Python expression that has some condition.

```
<Exp1> if condition else <Exp2>
```

First the `condition` is evaluated. If `condition` is `True`, then `<Exp1>` is evaluated and returned. If `condition` is `False`, then `<Exp2>` is evaluated and returned.

A conditional expression with more than one condition:

```
<Exp1> if condition else <Exp2> if condition else <Exp3>...
```

An example from [Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/):

```
age = 12
s = 'minor' if age < 21 else 'adult'
> minor
```

The value of `s` is conditioned to `age` value.

### 3.List Comprehensions with Conditionals

We put list comprehensions and conditionals together like this.

```
new_list = [<Conditional Expression> for <item> in <iterable>]

new_list = [<Exp1> if condition else <Exp2> if condition else <Exp3> for <item> in <iterable>]
```

Condition: *even* numbers will be added as `'even'`, the number three will be added as `'number three'` and the rest will be added as `'odd'`.

```
new_list = ['even' if x % 2 == 0 else 'number three' if x == 3 else 'odd' 
             for x in range(1, 10)]
> ['odd', 'even', 'number three', 'even', 'odd', 'even', 'odd', 'even', 'odd']
```

---

## The answer to the question

```
[f(x) for x in xs if x is not None else '']
```

Here we have a problem with the structure of the list: `for x in xs` should be at the end of the expression.

Correct way:

```
[f(x) if x is not None else '' for x in xs]
```

---

Further reading:

[Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: By far this is the best answer I can find here and elsewhere. really thank you Mr. `Guzman Ojero`

Comment: What's going on here `['even' if x % 2 == 0 else 'number three' if x == 3 else 'odd' 
             for x in range(1, 10)]`. Is that a nested ternary?

Comment: The section 'Case 3: more than one condition' confuses the very issue that this answer otherwise does well to clarify, namely the difference between the condition built into the comprehension loop which acts as a filter, and the condition of a ternary expression which the comprehension loop uses as a map.

Answer (score 86):

The specific problem has already been solved in previous answers, so I will address the general idea of using conditionals inside list comprehensions.

Here is an example that shows how conditionals can be written inside a list comprehension:

```
X = [1.5, 2.3, 4.4, 5.4, 'n', 1.5, 5.1, 'a']     # Original list

# Extract non-strings from X to new list
X_non_str = [el for el in X if not isinstance(el, str)]  # When using only 'if', put 'for' in the beginning

# Change all strings in X to 'b', preserve everything else as is
X_str_changed = ['b' if isinstance(el, str) else el for el in X]  # When using 'if' and 'else', put 'for' in the end
```

Note that in the first list comprehension for `X_non_str`, the order is:

> *expression* **for** *item* **in** *iterable* **if** *condition*

and in the last list comprehension for `X_str_changed`, the order is:

> *expression1*  **if**  *condition*  **else** *expression2* **for** *item* **in** *iterable*

I always find it hard to remember that *expression1* has to be before **if** and *expression2* has to be after **else**. My head wants both to be either before or after.

I guess it is designed like that because it resembles normal language, e.g. "I want to stay inside **if** it rains, **else** I want to go outside"

**In plain English** the two types of list comprehensions mentioned above could be stated as:

With only `if`:

> *extract_apple* **for** *apple* **in** *apple_box* **if** *apple_is_ripe*

and with `if/else`

> *mark_apple* **if** *apple_is_ripe* **else** *leave_it_unmarked* **for** *apple* **in** *apple_box*

Comment: You can have both. For example, this Buzzless Fizzbuzz: `vals = list(range(40)); [val if val % 3 else "Fizz" for val in vals if val % 5]` combines both an expression for what goes in the resulting list, as well as a filter condition.

Answer (score 52):

One way:

```
def change(x):
    if x is None:
        return f(x)
    else:
        return ''

result = [change(x) for x in xs]
```

Although then you have:

```
result = map(change, xs)
```

Or you can use a lambda inline.

Comment: This is also a good (maybe only) technique to use when you have to handle possible exceptions from the `if` expression or code in its or the `else`s statement block. The accepted answer is better for simple cases.

Answer (score 47):

Here is another illustrative example:

```
>>> print(", ".join(["ha" if i else "Ha" for i in range(3)]) + "!")
Ha, ha, ha!
```

It exploits the fact that `if i` evaluates to `False` for `0` and to `True` for all other values generated by the function `range()`. Therefore the list comprehension evaluates as follows:

```
>>> ["ha" if i else "Ha" for i in range(3)]
['Ha', 'ha', 'ha']
```

Answer (score 22):

```
[f(x) if x != None else '' for x in xs]
```

Syntax for list comprehension:

```
[item if condition else item for item in items]
[f(item) if condition else value for item in items]
[item if condition for item in items]
[value if condition else value1 if condition1 else value2]
```

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of the top answer, with a bit of clarification about list comprehensions.

Comment: Seems like you forgot the 'for' 
`[value if condition else value1 if condition1 else value2]`

Answer (score 11):

The other solutions are great for a single `if` / `else` construct. However, ternary statements within list comprehensions are arguably difficult to read.

Using a function aids readability, but such a solution is difficult to extend or adapt in a workflow where the mapping is an input. A dictionary can alleviate these concerns:

```
xs = [None, 'This', 'is', 'a', 'filler', 'test', 'string', None]

d = {None: '', 'filler': 'manipulated'}

res = [d.get(x, x) for x in xs]

print(res)

['', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'manipulated', 'test', 'string', '']
```

Answer (score 8):

It has to do with how the list comprehension is performed.

Keep in mind the following:

```
[ expression for item in list if conditional ]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for item in list:
    if conditional:
        expression
```

Where the `expression` is in a slightly different format (think switching the subject and verb order in a sentence).

Therefore, your code `[x+1 for x in l if x >= 45]` does this:

```
for x in l:
    if x >= 45:
        x+1
```

However, this code `[x+1 if x >= 45 else x+5 for x in l]` does this (after rearranging the `expression`):

```
for x in l:
    if x>=45: x+1
    else: x+5
```

Answer (score 3):

> Make a list from items in an iterable

It seems best to first generalize all the possible forms rather than giving specific answers to questions. Otherwise, the reader won't know how the answer was determined. Here are a few generalized forms I thought up before I got a headache trying to decide if a final else' clause could be used in the last form.

```
[expression1(item)                                        for item in iterable]

[expression1(item) if conditional1                        for item in iterable]

[expression1(item) if conditional1 else expression2(item) for item in iterable]

[expression1(item) if conditional1 else expression2(item) for item in iterable if conditional2]
```

The value of `item` doesn't need to be used in any of the conditional clauses. A `conditional3` can be used as a switch to either add or not add a value to the output list.

For example, to create a new list that eliminates empty strings or whitespace strings from the original list of strings:

```
newlist = [s for s in firstlist if s.strip()]
```

Comment: The second one gives an error as Tim [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50967467/11298075) in his comment, see also the [conditional statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in the python docs.
Which are quite unreadable to me. Summary: only `this if condition else that` or a normal expression is allowed. Not `value = this if condition` (which can be achieved with `value = this if condition else None`)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain it well but I just wanted to add a bit more about which conditional expression to use in a list comprehension.

As [the docs state](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), list comprehensions are used to create a list using a for-loop and has the general structure:

```
[expression for item in iterable (0 or more if/for clauses)]
```

It can create either:

1. a list by evaluating `expression` in iteration, or
2. a subsequence from `iterable` if an `if` statement follows the initial `for` statement

From the above general structure, we can see that `else` statement cannot follow a `for` statement; `for` can follow an `if` though; so the following is valid code:

```py
[y for x in range(5) if x % 2 == 0 for y in range(x)]
```

So any if-else control flow must be done in the `expression` evaluated above. Also since list comprehensions create a list, `expression` must be an expression that can be assigned to a variable. So conditional expressions such as a bare `if` cannot work because we don't know what the value should be if the condition is not True. It is similar to how defining variable `x` as `x = 10 if True` is a SyntaxError. So if `expression` includes a conditional statement, it must have `else` in it, similar to `x = 10 if True else 5` is OK to define variable `x`.

To sum up, using if/else should be treated as special case of case (1) above where `expression` is evaluated in iteration, with the caveat that `expression` includes a condition, like the following:

```py
[(expression1 if condition else expression2) for item in iterable]
```

---

- List comprehension where an `if` statement follows a `for` statement (case (2) above) is similar to the math notation to define a subset from a given set, so `[x for x in iterable if m<x<n]` is similar to `{x ∈ iterable | m<x<n}`.
- Since a list comprehension creates a list, it shouldn't be used if creating a list is not the goal; it shouldn't be used simply to write a one-line for-loop; so refrain from writing `[print(x) for x in range(5)]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need for ternary if/then/else. In my opinion your question calls for this answer:

```py
row = [unicode((x or '').strip()) for x in row]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine conditional logic in a comprehension:

```
 ps = PorterStemmer()
 stop_words_english = stopwords.words('english')
 best = sorted(word_scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:10000]
 bestwords = set([w for w, s in best])


 def best_word_feats(words):
   return dict([(word, True) for word in words if word in bestwords])

 # with stemmer
 def best_word_feats_stem(words):
   return dict([(ps.stem(word), True) for word in words if word in bestwords])

 # with stemmer and not stopwords
 def best_word_feats_stem_stop(words):
   return dict([(ps.stem(word), True) for word in words if word in bestwords and word not in stop_words_english])
```

Answer (score -3):

```
# coding=utf-8

def my_function_get_list():
    my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    # You may use map() to convert each item in the list to a string, 
    # and then join them to print my_list

    print("Affichage de my_list [{0}]".format(', '.join(map(str, my_list))))

    return my_list


my_result_list = [
   (
       number_in_my_list + 4,  # Condition is False : append number_in_my_list + 4 in my_result_list
       number_in_my_list * 2  # Condition is True : append number_in_my_list * 2 in my_result_list
   )

   [number_in_my_list % 2 == 0]  # [Condition] If the number in my list is even

   for number_in_my_list in my_function_get_list()  # For each number in my list
]

print("Affichage de my_result_list [{0}]".format(', '.join(map(str, my_result_list))))
```

(venv) $ python list_comp.py 
Affichage de my_list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
Affichage de my_result_list [0, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9]

So, for you:
`row = [('', unicode(x.strip()))[x is not None] for x in row]`

Comment: What does *"Affichage de..."* mean? Is it French?

Comment: @PeterMortensen French indeed, means "Displaying / overview of".

So `Displaying / overview of my_result_list`