# `elif` in list comprehension conditionals

Tags: python, list-comprehension, conditional-operator

Consider this example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for values in l:
    if values == 1:
        print('yes')
    elif values == 2:
        print('no')
    else:
        print('idle')
```

Rather than `print`ing the results, I want to use a list comprehension to create a list of results, like `['yes', 'no', 'idle', 'idle', 'idle']`.

How can we represent the `elif` logic in a list comprehension? Up until now, I have only used `if` and `else` in list comprehension, as in [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280).

Comment: Think about how you would write the explicit loop using only `if` and `else`, if `elif` didn't exist. Then translate that into what you already know about using `if` and `else` (i.e., the ternary operator) in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 401, accepted):

Python's [conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.3/whatsnew/pep-308.html) were designed exactly for this sort of use-case:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> ['yes' if v == 1 else 'no' if v == 2 else 'idle' for v in l]
['yes', 'no', 'idle', 'idle', 'idle']
```

Comment: There's some interesting history in the syntax. For many years before their introduction "tertiary expressions" were one of the five most-requested changes in the language. Since Guido van Rossum explicitly designed it as a statement-based language, he firmly resisted for a long time (tertiary expressions, and particularly their abuse, are sources of much obscurity in code). When he finally succumbed, he announced he had deliberately chosen a syntax that discouraged overuse. As usual, he did an elegant design job nevertheless.

Comment: Ternary, dammit (he wrote, noticing his dyslexic mistake too late to edit).

Comment: While I up-vote this answer, I want to mention this: for 1 pair of if/else is easy to read, 2 pairs: it's getting harder to understand. Don't even mention 3 pairs. If the expression needs 3 or more pairs, a dictionary or a separate function will make things easier to read and understand.

Comment: I would like to add not a solution for this problem, but a reminder of clean code: since this list comprehension has three conditionals, it could probably be refactored into a more descriptive method. My point is this: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FunctionLength.html :)

Comment: I stumbled upon a case where I needed an elif, but only two values. Using this example, I would've needed just `['yes', 'no']` to be made.


To do this, you can do:




`['yes' if v == 1 else 'no' for v in l if values in [1,2]]`.

I currently can't think of a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 65):

```
>>> d = {1: 'yes', 2: 'no'}
>>> [d.get(x, 'idle') for x in l]
['yes', 'no', 'idle', 'idle', 'idle']
```

Comment: I think this form is a lot easier to digest than trying to do a really long and complicated if/else logic within the list comp

Comment: @jdi Though conditional-expressions may not be to your taste, they *were* specifically designed to handle if-elif-elif-else chains, just as the OP requested.  They aren't hard to learn and can gracefully handle situations that aren't as amenable to dictionary lookup logic:  ``'A' if grade>=90 else 'B' if grade>=80 else 'C' if grade>=70 else 'F'``.

Comment: If there an advantage of defining `d` outside the comprehension?

Comment: The reason I like the list comprehension better is that it reads just like English. Even a non-programmer would be able to understand what it does. With this solution you have to understand the dict.get() method.

Comment: This is especially useful if there are even more than three options.

Answer (score 50):

You can, sort of.

Note that when you use sytax like:

```
['yes' if v == 1 else 'no' for v in l]
```

You are using the ternary form of the if/else operator (if you're familiar with languages like C, this is like the `?:` construct: `(v == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no')`).

The ternary form of the if/else operator doesn't have an 'elif' built in, but you can simulate it in the 'else' condition:

```
['yes' if v == 1 else 'no' if v == 2 else 'idle' for v in l]
```

This is like saying:

```
for v in l:
    if v == 1 :
        print 'yes'
    else:
        if v == 2:
            print 'no'
        else:
            print 'idle'
```

So there's no direct 'elif' construct like you asked about, but it can be simulated with nested if/else statements.

Comment: Great explanation... +1 for including the equivalent expression using the regular if else syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension is you are going to create another list from original.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> result_map = {1: 'yes', 2: 'no'}
>>> [result_map[x] if x in result_map else 'idle' for x in l]
['yes', 'no', 'idle', 'idle', 'idle']
```

Answer (score 3):

Another easy way is to use conditional list comprehension like this:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
print [[["no","yes"][v==1],"idle"][v!=1 and v!=2] for v in l]
```

gives you the correct anwer:

```
['yes', 'no', 'idle', 'idle', 'idle']
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

print ([['idle','no','yes'][2*(n==1)+(n==2)] for n in l])
```

Comment: I think this is quite clever, but not very legible.