# Nested if / else clauses in List Comprehension Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Starting with the following list comprehension:

```
new_list = [re.sub(r'replace_a', 'with__b', i)
             if not re.findall(r'find_pattern', i, re.M) else 
            re.sub(r'replace_c', r'with__d', i)
            for i in old_list]
```

Now I would like to add an if condition after `else` that replaces another pattern using `re.sub()`. I tried with:

```
new_list = [re.sub(r'replace_a', 'with_b', i)
             if not re.findall(r'find_pattern', i, re.M) else
           (re.sub(r'replace_c', r'with_d', i)
             if foo == re.match("pattern", foo))
           for i in old_list]
```

Tried to figure out the proper way to do it with list comprehensions but had no luck.

Comment: The final `if` clause needs to go at the end I think since it's dosen't have an assosed `else`. You could write out a `for` loop you know, or at least add some line breaks to make this readable

Comment: What's the error you are getting? I think you might just need to add in a final `else`, because it looks like this pattern other than that  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987533/1011724. Or maybe try remove the parenthesis around you last `else`...`if` clause. But also `foo == re.match("pattern", foo)` doesn't depend on anything in the list comprehension so are you trying to make that entire clause conditional on something external? Edit your Q to add line breaks,   explain your desired logic and drop the regex and add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem isn't the list comprehension; it's the conditional expression that is missing its `else`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands apologies, added the line breaks. I tried with the for loop but I have problems when I append the elements to the new list.

Comment: @Dan yes, as you said it missed the final else. With `foo = re.match` I wanted to add an additional condition based on the value of a variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will read much more easily as a regular for loop:

```
new_list = []
for i in old_list:
    if not re.findall(r'find_pattern', i, re.M):
        new_list.append(re.sub(r'replace_a', 'with_b', i))
    elif foo == re.match("pattern", foo):
        new_list.append(re.sub(r'replace_c', r'with_d', i))
    # else:
    #    i
```

Your problem is that a conditional expression must *always* take an `else` clause, because it has to have some value whether or not the condition is true. With an `if` *statement*, however, you can omit the `else`. The above, for instance, has the ability to make `new_list` shorter than `old_list`, as not every `i` needs to result in a call to `new_list.append`. Uncommenting the `else` results in the same result as jpp's answer.

If you insist on using a list comprehension, then you can format it to make it more readable. Consider

```
new_list = [re.sub(r'replace_pattern_a', 'with_pattern_b', i)
               if not re.findall(r'find_pattern', i, re.M) else 
            re.sub(r'replace_pattern_c', r'with_pattern_d', i) 
               if foo == re.match("pattern", foo) else
            i
            for i in old_list]
```

although the conditional expression really isn't designed for such nesting. This visually separates the expressions that could be added to the new list from the conditions used to make the decision, but I'm not a big fan. There are other ways to format that make different trade-offs, but IMO the regular `for` loop is superior.

---

As jpp mentions, another way to refactor is to define a generator function:

```
def foo(old_list):
    for i in old_list:
        if not re.findall(r'find_pattern', i, re.M):
            yield re.sub(r'replace_a', 'with_b', i))
        elif foo == re.match("pattern", foo):
            yield re.sub(r'replace_c', r'with_d', i))
        else:
            yield i

new_list = list(foo())
```

which would have its pros and cons as well. (I think enumerating those is probably beyond the scope of this answer, but it does fall somewhere between the two extremes of a single list comprehension and an explicit `for` loop. It also comes closest to the construct I miss from my Perl days, the `do` statement, which is something like a `lambda` that doesn't take any arguments, but can contain arbitrary statements.)

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed explanation and for the solution using a `for` loop. I haven't thought of putting `re.sub` in new.list(append). Have a lot to learn. ~faber

Comment: Looking at it more, I'd probably use a temporary variable anyway. `x = re.sub(...); new_list.append(x)`. That also has the benefit of letting you defer the call to `new_list.append` until after the `if` statement. Just set `x` as appropriate in each branch, then call `new_list.append(x)` at the end.

Comment: In my opinion, an even more readable option is to use a generator function and `yield` items. Then call `list` when required. Doubt there's any performance improvement here, but this removes boilerplate code of instantiating a list and using `list.append`.

Comment: chepner and jpp, thank you again. I will definitely take in your suggestions to better code.

Comment: @chepner thank you for showing the solution with a generator function. Very interesting and plus, it looks neat.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify an `else` condition for when none of the conditions are met. For example:

```
import re

old_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

new_list = [re.sub(r'replace_pattern_a', 'with_pattern_b', i) if not re.findall(r'find_pattern', i, re.M) \
            else re.sub(r'replace_pattern_c', r'with_pattern_d', i) if foo == re.match("pattern", foo) \
            else i for i in old_list]

# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

However, this is unreadable. I suggest, if performance is not an issue, you create a function to provide this manipulation with standard `if` / `elif` / `else` constructs.

Comment: At the very least, a regular `for` loop that explicitly calls `new_list.append` would be fine.

Comment: @jpp, thank you. I've been struggling to fix it and I see now how easy it was.

Comment: @chepner I tried for loop and new_list.append but it doesn't save the elements in the list.