# Making use of dict.get for if elif and else in List Comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I wanted to implement `if` `elif` and `else` inside a list comprehension and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987535/2126357) stackoverflow answer I found a way of doing the same.

So let me explain what the issue is:

As per the answer, the `dict.get()` can be used in following way to use conditionals in list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> d = {1: 'yes', 2: 'no'}
>>> [d.get(x, 'idle') for x in l]
['yes', 'no', 'idle', 'idle', 'idle']
```

Seems nice and good. But I am running into a different kind of problem.
So I need to use the same method to work with the index of some other list. Allow me to explain:

```
perc = np.array([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])

d= {0: 0, len(perc):1}

result = [d.get(x, (perc[x-1]+perc[x])/2) for x in range(len(perc)+1)]
```

So in short I want my output to be 0 and 1 for x being 0 and len(perc), or else average of previous value and current value.

Now, this is giving me an error:

```
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

My question is, wasn't `dict.get(key[, default])`defined as:

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.

Now clearly 5 as a key is in the dictionary as `len(perc)=5`, then why the default condition is being checked first, which obviously will give an error as there is no `5th` index in the array perc.

### Edit

As mentioned in the comment by [Klaus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d), The expression is evaluated before .get() is called. If that's the case and nothing can be done about this, then is there any other way I can achieve this without using loops?

Comment: The error is not raised by accesding the dictionary key but by accessing the array. There is no index `5` in a 5 item array.

Comment: Hey Klaus, I've already mentioned that in my question, that it is accessing the 5th index from array. My question is, as per the definition of dict.get(), shouldn't it check the dictionary first where 5 as a key is already present. Because in that case, it won't need to check the default.

Comment: The expression is evaluated before `.get()` is called.

Comment: In that case, isn't the way it's defined in the docs.python wrong?
It says:
Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.

Comment: No, it is correct. The default is the *result* of the *evaluated* expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want like this?

```
import numpy as np
perc = np.array([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])
d= {0: 0, len(perc):1}
result = [d.get(x, (lambda y: ((perc[y-1]+perc[y])/2) if y < len(perc) else 99999)(x)) for x in range(len(perc)+8)]
print(result)
#[0, 0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875, 1, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999]
```

Comment: Yup works perfectly. I should've thought of using lambda. Silly me. I've upvoted. I'll wait for someone else to answer as well, to see if there is more elegant way or method; if not, I'll accept this as the answer.