# List Comprehension nested in Dict Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I want to create a dict with lists as values, where the content on the lists depends on whether or not the key (numbers 1 to 100) is dividable by 3,5 and/or 7

The output would be like this:

```
{
    1: ['nodiv3', 'nodiv5', 'nodiv7'],
    3: ['div3', 'nodiv5', 'nodiv7'],
    15: ['div3', 'div5', 'nodiv7'],
}
```

Similar questions where about filtering the list/values, not creating them.

```
dict_divider = {}
for x in range(0,101):
    div_list= []
    if x % 3 == 0:
        div_list.append('div3')
    else:
        div_list.append('nodiv3')
    if x % 5 == 0:
        div_list.append('div5')
    else:
        div_list.append('nodiv5')
    if x % 7 == 0:
        div_list.append('div7')
    else:
        div_list.append('nodiv7')
    dict_divider[x] = div_list
```

This works just fine, but is there a way to do this with a pythonic one-/twoliner?

Something along like this: `d = dict((val, range(int(val), int(val) + 2)) for val in ['1', '2', '3'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a one liner that isnt even that complicated :)

```
my_dict = {}
for i in range(100):
    my_dict[i] = ['div' + str(n) if i % n == 0 else 'nodiv' + str(n) for n in [3,5,7]]
```

Comment: however how would you do it if it HAD to be different values, so not just div/nodiv but div3/nodiv3 and so on?

Comment: you could use some mor else/if statements for that purpose i guess, but at some point its getting ugly.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987533/11951277

Comment: My approach is about 400% more efficient than this answer, according to `timeit`.

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic is not about one or two liners. In my opinion is (mainly) about readability, perhaps this could be considered more *pythonic*:

```
def label(n, divisor):
    return f"{'' if n % divisor == 0 else 'no'}div{divisor}"


def find_divisors(n, divisors=[3, 5, 7]):
    return [label(n, divisor) for divisor in divisors]


dict_divider = {x: find_divisors(x) for x in range(1, 101)}

print(dict_divider)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to do all these brute-force divisions. Every third number is divisible by three, every seventh number is divisible by seven, etc:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...  <-- range(10)
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 ...  <-- mod 3

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...  <-- range(10)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 ...  <-- mod 7
```

So the best approach should take advantage of that fact, using the repeating patterns of modulo. Then, we can just zip the range with however many iterators you want to use.

```
import itertools

def divs(n):
    L = [f"div{n}"] + [f"nodiv{n}"] * (n - 1)
    return itertools.cycle(L)

repeaters = [divs(n) for n in (3, 5, 7)]
d = {x: s for x, *s in zip(range(101), *repeaters)}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write a second loop so that you only have to write `if...else` only once

```py
dict_divider = {}
div_check_lst = [3, 5, 7]
for x in range(0,101):
    div_list= []
    for div_check in div_check_lst:
        if x % div_check == 0:
            div_list.append(f'div{str(div_check)}')
        else:
            div_list.append(f'nodiv{str(div_check)}')
    dict_divider[x] = div_list
```

or

```py
dict_divider = {x:[f'{'no' * x % div_check != 0}div{str(div_check)}' for x in range(0,101) for div_check in div_check_lst]}
```