# How can I create a mapping of intervals to a number, with constant look up time? (if this is possible?)

Tags: python, mapping, intervals

I am trying to create a mapping, where we are given an `integer n`, and also a bunch of intervals that map to random numbers.

e.g. n = 55, and say we have intervals: `[1:3]->-2,[4:10]->-3,[11:25]->-4,[26:44]->-5,[45:66]->-6, etc.`

Is it possible/how can I create a mapping that is constant time, so that for any given n, I can find the corresponding interval, then the correct mapping to the negative number?

My thoughts are to create a dictionary, with keys as the intervals, and the values as the negative number- however would this be constant time lookup for any given n?

Comment: what do you know about n? what do you know about the intervals?

Comment: What do you mean by "the correct mapping to the negative number"? You want to take an integer and then lookup the value where the integer is in a range?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't the clearest, n is an integer that falls inside exactly one of the intervals

Comment: So following the example, if n=27, I want the function to return -5. Is n=2 then I want the function to return -2

Comment: If `n` is restricted to a finite number of values and it's convenient to store them in memory, then a dict with each value would be constant time lookup. Or if up at 66 you have the mapping above and for n > 66 you have, say, -7. That would also work with a dict by using a default value for any missing keys. A list can achieve all that where you first check that `n < len(list_of_values)` and then fetch by index. If it's not practical to store the whole mapping, then you can use  bisect thresholds, but with O(logn) complexity.

Comment: I know the intervals above don't quite work in coding terms either, like [1:3] is meaningless, but I think it is clear what I meant! In my code I would do [I for I in range(1,4)]

Comment: What do you know about the NUMBER of intervals?

Comment: @Reti43 n can be huge 10^5, so storing each number won't be practical- sorry should have mentioned this too!

Comment: @Eyal, the number of intervals will be say around 100

Comment: @user15877202 you will probably have to loop over the intervals and run a comparison to see if n contained in the interval

Comment: Thanks Lain, that's what I thought. But if the intervals were sorted, is there a faster was to look up then?

Comment: I don't think 10**5 is really that big of a deal. Do you have any memory restrictions? If your intervals are sorted, you can use bisect like I mentioned above. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66762595/efficient-way-to-sort-by-number-thresholds-in-python).

Comment: Even if you define your map with something like `d = {i: -i for i in range(10000)}` so that all numbers are different and you need that many objects in memory, they still don't take up more than [1 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316760/2243104).

Comment: And a numpy array would be even more memory efficient, assuming the list/array approach is practical.

Comment: Thanks Reti- this does seem to work. I am coding on CodeChef, a competitive website, so conscious about time and space! But this does work so thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the `portion` library)

There's a Python library named `portion` that explicitly supports this use case. `portion` has an `IntervalDict` class that allows you to map intervals with data and that has an API close to the built-in `dict`.

Based on the provided example:

```
>>> import portion as P
>>> d = P.IntervalDict()
>>> d[P.closed(1, 3)] = -2
>>> d[P.closed(4, 10)] = -3
>>> d[P.closed(11, 25)] = -4
>>> # ... and so on
>>> d[16]
-4
>>> d[2]
-2
>>> # ... and so on
```

Lookups are in O(n) where n is the number of distinct values in the mapping (i.e. number of distinct integers in your case). A O(log(n)) implementation is currently in progress (where n is the number of disjoint intervals).

Link to the documentation: https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion (look for "Map intervals to data").

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution would be to create an array of size `n`, and for each index, initialize it with the target value. This is wasteful (for example if n is really big, and you have just one interval).
Constructing the array is done in `O(n)` time, but accessing an array by index is `O(1)`.

EDIT: If the number of given intervals is a constant and not a function of n, then iterating the intervals to find the right one can be done in `O(1)` time. In this case you don't need any `dict` or `array`.