# How to add digit in the beginning of string array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

e.g. I have this array

```
list=['123', '4', '56']
```

I want to add '0' in the beginning of list array that has 1 or 2 digit. So the output will be:

```
list=['123', '004', '056']
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pad zeroes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/how-to-pad-zeroes-to-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

Use `zfill` method:

```
In [1]: '1'.zfill(3)
Out[1]: '001'

In [2]: '12'.zfill(3)
Out[2]: '012'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension, we can prepend the string `'00'` to each number in the list, then retain the final 3 characters only:

```py
list = ['123', '4', '56']
output = [('00' + x)[-3:] for x in list]
print(output)  # ['123', '004', '056']
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [How to pad zeroes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/how-to-pad-zeroes-to-a-string), you should use [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```py
mylist = ['123', '4', '56']
output = [x.zfill(3) for x in mylist]
```

Alternatively, you could (though I don't know why you would) use [`str.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust)

```py
output = [x.rjust(3, "0") for x in mylist]
```

or [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```py
output = [f"{x:0>3}" for x in mylist]
```

Comment: If it does then this question is a duplicate. I just put his code in a list comprehension and listed alternatives because Tim asked me to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this would be a very easy to read example, but not the shortest.

Basically, we iterate through the lists elements, check if the length is 2 or 1. Based on that we will add the correct amount of `'0'`

```
lst=['123', '4', '56']
new = []
for numString in lst:
    if len(numString) == 2:
        new.append('0'*1+numString)
    elif len(numString) == 1:
        new.append('0'*2+numString)
    else:
        new.append(numString)
print(new)
```

Also I kind of had to include it (list comprehension).But this is barely readable,so I gave the above example. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987483/elif-in-list-comprehension-conditionals) for list comprehension with `if, elif, else`

```
lst=['123', '4', '56']
new = ['0'*1+numString if len(numString) == 2 else '0'*2+numString if len(numString) == 1 else numString  for numString in lst]
print(new)
```

output

```
['123', '004', '056']
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually help me, I can understand this easily.

Comment: This approach doesn't scale very well for padding numbers of arbitrary length.

Comment: This is an insanely verbose answer, considering Python has builtin ways to do [zero padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/how-to-pad-zeroes-to-a-string).

Answer (score -2):

trying into integer and add preceding zero/s then convert into a string and replace the element in the same position  and the same list

```html
list=["3","45","111"]
n=len(list)
for i in range(0,n):
        list[i] = str(f"{int(list[i]):03}")
```

You can check the solution for this in [link](http://www.exsamplez.com/?p=51)