# Python: elif statements using list comprehension

Tags: python, datetime, list-comprehension

Lets take the next reproducible example:

1. I have a numpy array with a sequence of `datetime.datetime` elements in an hourly frequency,
2. From that array, I want to create a list `datesVect` which I want to be True for `datetimes` between Februrary and April and else False.

following the validated answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987483/elif-in-list-comprehension-conditionals) and the explanation of the usage of list comprehension conditionals of [this post](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/python/python-elif-in-list-comprehension-conditionals-example-code/) I try to do it with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

#Setting the startdate and creating the data range array:

startDate = datetime.datetime(2023,1,1)
dateHour = np.array([startDate + datetime.timedelta(0,3600*n) for n in range(8760)])

#Creating the desired list

datesVect = [True if j.month < 5 else True if j.month > 1 else False for j in dateHour]
```

Instead of getting the desired result I get a list full of `True` values:

```
In [211]: all(datesVect)
Out[211]: True
```

Anyone knows why I don't get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to just use the `and` operator. Your current code is functioning similar to the `or` operator, hence why you get an array of all True values. To be between Feb and April the month must be greater than 1 and less than 5.

```
datesVect = [True if (j.month < 5 and j.month > 1) else False for j in dateHour]
```

Comment: In this example you don't even need an if else you could simply do `datesVect = [(j.month < 5 and j.month > 1) for j in dateHour]` because the statement inside of the () will just evaluate to True or False`