# Python Dictionary value assignment with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, numpy

I would like to take a python dictionary of lists, convert the lists to numpy arrays, and restore them in the dictionary using list comprehension.

For example, if I had a dictionary

```
myDict = {'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,6,7,8], 'C':'str', 'D':'str'}
```

I wish to convert the lists under keys A and B to numpy arrays, but leave the other parts of the dictionary untouched. Resulting in

```
myDict = {'A':array[1,2,3,4], 'B':array[5,6,7,8], 'C':'str', 'D':'str'}
```

I can do this with a for loop:

```
import numpy as np

for key in myDict:
    if key not in ('C', 'D'):
        myDict[key] = np.array(myDict[key])
```

But is it possible to do this with list comprehension? Something like

```
[myDict[key] = np.array(myDict[key]) for key in myDict if key not in ('C', 'D')]
```

Or indeed what is the fastest most efficient way to achieve this for a large dictionaries of long lists.
Thanks, labjunky

Comment: The answers of Haidro and Ashwini Chaudhary, below, are very similar and appeared concurrently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Python 2.7 and above, you can use a [dictionary comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
myDict = {'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,6,7,8], 'C':'str', 'D':'str'}
myDict = {key:np.array(val) if key not in {'C', 'D'} else val for key, val in myDict.iteritems()}
```

If you're below version 2.7 (and hence don't have dictionary comprehensions), you can do:

```
myDict = {'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,6,7,8], 'C':'str', 'D':'str'}
dict((key, np.array(val) if key not in {'C', 'D'} else val for key, val in myDict.iteritems())
```

Comment: Nice, but I get <ipython-input-135-01de37e639d5> in <dictcomp>((key, val))
----> 1 myDict = {key:np.array(val) if val not in {'C', 'D'} else val for key, val in myDict.iteritems()}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Try `ęlse key:val`. It seems Python thinks in `else val` you want to use `val` as a key (that's why it says `unhashable type`.

Comment: @Cucu No, it was a simple typo of me checking if the list was in the set, when I should have been checking if the value (which can't be unhashable) was in the set

Answer (score 1):

To change all items except `'C'` and `'D'`:

```
>>> myDict = {'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,6,7,8], 'C':'str', 'D':'str'}
>>> ignore = {'C', 'D'}
>>> new_dict = {k : v if k in ignore else np.array(v) for k,v in myDict.iteritems()}
```

the above dict-comprehension returns a new dictionary, to modify the original dict, try:

```
#myDict.viewkeys() - ignore --> set(['A', 'B'])
for key in myDict.viewkeys() - ignore:
    myDict[key] = np.array(myDict[key])
```

or if you only want to change `'A'` and `'B'`:

```
for key in {'A', 'B'}:
    myDict[key] = np.array(myDict[key])
```

Comment: spelling of 'ingore' second line

Answer (score 0):

To

> take a python dictionary of lists, convert the lists to numpy arrays, and restore them in the dictionary using list comprehension.

I would do:

```
myDict = {'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,6,7,8], 'C':'str', 'D':'str'}

def modifier(item):
    if type(item) == list:
        return np.array(item)
    else:
        return item

mod_myDict = {key: modifier(myDict[key]) for key in myDict.keys()}
```

The function then sets the restrictions you require in this case changing all lists into arrays. This returns:

```
{'A': array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 'B': array([5, 6, 7, 8]), 'C': 'str', 'D': 'str'}
```

Note: I believe this should be made shorter by using conditions in the `if` statement but I can't seem to figure it, something like

```
mod_myDict = {key: np.array(myDict[key]) if type(myDict[key])==list else key: myDict[key] for key in myDict.keys()}
```

That however, raises an error. Perhaps some more intelligent person than I knows why!

Comment: You may want something like the conditional comprehensions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/python-if-else-in-list-comprehension