# Python - loop inside ternary operator

Tags: python, ternary-operator

I am learning python, and trying to use some ternary operators.

I am trying to make the function below using a ternary:

```
def array_count9(nums):
    count = 0
    for i in nums:
        if i == 9:
            count += 1
    return count
```

I have tried:

```
def array_count9(nums):
    count = 0
    count += 1 if i == 9 for i in nums else pass
    return count
```

which threw a `SyntaxError`, then after looking around I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319053/python-inline-if-statement-else-do-nothing) and changed my code for what I believed was better ordering:

```
def array_count9(nums):
    count = 0
    count += 1 if i == 9 else pass for i in nums
    return count
```

Still receiving `SyntaxError` which is pointing at the `for`. I've tried using parentheses in different places too.

I have looked around and there are other related threads such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22734813/6542133) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199757/python-ternary-operator-without-else), which resulted in me trying this:

```
def array_count9(nums):
    count = 0
    count += 1 if i == 9 else count == count for i in nums
    return count
```

I've also tried other resources by searching Google, but I can't quite work it out. Please teach me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the most idiomatic way to write the code:

```
def array_count9(nums):
    return sum(num == 9 for num in nums)
```

But you could also do this if you want to use the if/else construct:

```
def array_count9(nums):
    return sum(1 if num == 9 else 0 for num in nums)
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this works, however I still don't understand why what I've used isn't working. Can you explain?

Comment: @JakeStokes I'm not sure how to explain... I think all of your attempts were simply syntax errors? List comprehension in Python results in an iterator of values... there's nothing like what you were trying to do.

Comment: Hmm.. there seem to be people doing what I'm trying to do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319053/python-inline-if-statement-else-do-nothing) but I can't make it work. Can you confirm that I'm doing something different?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `1 if foo else 2`. (That's in my second solution.) It was the loop that didn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The blueprint for a ternary operator is:

```
condition_is_true if condition else condition_is_false
```

The statement where the syntax error occurs is at

```
count += 1 if i == 9 else pass for i in nums
```

ie `count += 1` does not meet the blueprint specification, because `condition_is_true` should not need to be evaluated.

Comment: So after wasting a lot of time, you've helped me understand why it wouldn't work. Thanks a lot @nnja

Answer (score 0):

Okay so using your examples was a little tricky because a ternary operator can't include anything outside it's specific blueprint; that being the for loop you're trying to pass with it.

```
count += 1 if i == 9 for i in nums else pass
```

So after fiddling around with the code:

```
def array_count9(nums):
count = 0
count += 1 if i == 9 for i in nums else pass
return count
```

I was sure you were looking for something that works involving ternary operators and that for loop. So keeping your goal in mind, this is what I came up with.

```
numss = [3,6,9,10,35]

def count9(nums):
    count = 0
    a = count + 1
    for i in nums:
        count = (a if i == 9 else count) #This being the ternary operator
    return count

print (count9(numss))
```

Hope this helps.