# List comprehension with condition

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension, generator-expression

Suppose I have a list `a = [0, 1, 2]`.

I know that I can use a list comprehension like so, to get a list where the values are doubled:

```
>>> b = [x*2 for x in a]
>>> b
[0, 2, 4]
```

How can I make it so that the list comprehension ignores `0` values in the input list, so that the result is `[2, 4]`?

My attempt failed:

```
>>> b = [x*2 if x != 0 else None for x in a]
>>> b
[None, 2, 4]
```

---

<sub>See [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280) if you are trying to make a list comprehension that *uses different logic* based on a condition.</sub>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
b = [x*2 for x in a if x != 0]
```

if you put your condition at the end you do not need an else (infact cannot have an else there)

Answer (score 8):

Following the pattern:

```
[ <item_expression>
  for <item_variables> in <iterator>
  if <filtering_condition>
]
```

we can solve it like:

```
>>> lst = [0, 1, 2]
>>> [num
... for num in lst
... if num != 0]
[1, 2]
```

It is all about forming an if condition testing "nonzero" value.