# if Element in List contains a word | Python

Tags: python, string, list, substring, list-comprehension

Say I have a list:

```
my_list = ["A", "B", "haha_test_haha", "C"]
```

I want to remove any and all elements that hold the substring `test`.

Output:

```
my_list = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

I've been trying list comprehensions with no luck. This would be the desired solution.

Note: I need only `test` to be removed. Not a list of words to remove.

---

My attempt:

```
my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'ahahtestaagaga']

my_list = [remove for e in my_list if e.substring('test')]

print([sa for sa in a if not any(sb in sa for sb in b)])
```

Comment: Please show the list comprehension you tried. And explain what happened. Show some output and explain what you want your code to do differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442091/list-comprehension-with-condition

Comment: I will append attempt to post. Sorry for downvotes. Forgot minimal code example

Comment: `e.substring('test')`? Why are you trying to use `e.substring`? Are you asking how to check if a string is a substring of another? You attempts really don't make any sense.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wasn't sure on what I was trying to use, admittedly. My desired solution was a list-comprehension, which has since been provided. 'not in' means less function use, which is great for me who is learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what it would look like as a for loop, so for the sake of the example, let's build a new list (even though it's inefficient), you want to capture things that don't have "test" as a substring:

```
new_list = []
for x in my_list:
    if "test" not in x:
        new_list.append(x)
```

So what would that look like as a comprehension?

```
my_list = [x for x in my_list if "test" not in x]
```

Comment: The for-loop is incorrect. Try it with `["A", "B", "test_foo", "haha_test_haha", "C"]`. It is also unnecessarily inefficient

Comment: Your loop is not equivalent to the list comprehension at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're right, good catch. I was trying to provide a for loop so OP could visualize it better, but since it doesn't work, I've removed it and added a better example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [word for word in my_list if 'test' not in word]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.