# Find next integer not in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to find the first integer after a given integer that is not in a list of integers, nanIndices.  I try

```
next(x for not (x in nanIndices))
```

and

```
next(x for x >0 and x not in nanIndices)
```

and

```
 next(x for x not in nanIndices)
```

and get

```
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

in both cases.  I then try

```
 next(x for x in range(1,1000) and x not in nanIndices)
```

and get

```
*** NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

What I particularly don't understand is that

```
next(x for x in nanIndices)
```

works fine but

```
next(x for x not in nanIndices)
```

gives a syntax error

The suggested solution does not work because it returns an array, not the next integer to satisfy the condition.

Comment: The syntax for a condition in a comprehension is `if`, not `and`. The `for x in range(1, 1000)` part is not a condition so it does not make sense to write `and` here to add another condition. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442091/list-comprehension-with-condition).

Comment: Is `nanIndices` sorted? If so, you can use [`bisect.bisect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) to find where to start looking.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnnyMopp.  It is ordered and >= 0.  So bisect.bisect_left(nanIndices, -1) works for me.