# Can't get ternary operator to work

Tags: python

So I have a double problem. I have `selectedCards` list, which contains 2 elements - card rank and suit, in this format: `['6', 'c']`

`club = u"\u2663" # Unicode codepoint for club`

`newList = [club for i in selectedCards if i == 'c' else i]`

I want to change 'c' into graphical representation of club, but this expression not working. I tried searching a lot but couldn't find what's wrong. It says: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Second problem, If I remove else statement, then it works, but it does not output what I want, it looks like this: `[u'\u2663']`, even thought print(club) outputs ♣.

EDIT: `newList = [club if i == 'c' else i for i in selectedCards]` is the correct syntax, thanks to xtofl.

Comment: It's a good idea to split two questions into... two separate questions :)

Comment: is `selectedCards` then a list of two-element lists?

Comment: It's a list of 2 elements, like: `['A', 'h']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are better off with a dict:

```
symbols = {
  'c': u"\u2663",
  'h': u"....hearts",
  ...
}

newList = [symbols[card] for card in selectedCards]
```

(or if you want to go functional:

```
map( symbols.get, selectedCards )
```

)

As for the 1st problem: cfr https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260304/6610

For the 2nd, printing, problem: python just gives you 'a' list representation; if you want it in string form, this did the trick for me:

```
print("".join(newList))
```

(hint: it would be wise to represent you card in a `Card` class containing all this logic, somewhat like

```
class Card:
   def __init__(self, rank, suit):
      self.rank = rank
      self.suit = suit

   symbols = {'c': u"\u2663", ...}

   def __str__(self):
      return "".join([self.rank, Card.symbols[self.suit]])
```

)

Comment: I know there are many options to achieve same task, I still wonder why that way does not work. Anyways, your implementation, gives me error `KeyError: 'Q'`, where Q changes depending on rank. I think I need to include condition here to check if it's rank or a suit.

Comment: For an answer to the list comprehension question, do take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4260304/6610

Comment: xtofl, yep this solved: `newList = [club if i == 'c' else i for i in selectedCards]`! But again I get it like this `['Q', u'\u2663']` which is my 2nd problem.

Comment: Wouldn't `__str__` be more appropriate than `__repr__` as this method gives a nice to print string rather than the actual values of the object attributes? see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__