# List comprehension double loop with if

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists `A` and `B` where `B` is a superset of `A`.

I would like boolean list of that specifies whether an element of `A` is equal to an element of `B`. The superset list `B` is ordered.

If have tried this:

```
res = [(1 for a in A if a is b) for b in B]
```

According to other answers this should work. But in my case it returns a list of generators.. How can I end up with just a normal list. Something like:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
B = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
res = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Can you edit your post so I can see what it returns?

Comment: *"it returns a list of generators"* - that's exactly what you're asking for. If you want to flatten the result, ditch the parentheses. Note that you're creating a Cartesian product, though, which isn't what you say you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get generator objects back is because you use `()` , hence those make generator expressions, which are not evaluated until you iterate through them.

What you really should be using if simple `in` operator. Example -

```
>>> A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
>>> B = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> res = [1 if x in A else 0 for x in B]
>>> res
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

---

If your usecase is more complex and you have to use `is` operator to compare elements of `A` and `B` . Then you can use `any()` function to iterate through the generator expression and return `True` if a match is found, other `False` . Example -

```
res = [1 if any(a is b for a in A) else 0 for b in B]
```

Demo -

```
>>> A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
>>> B = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> res = [1 if any(a is b for a in A) else 0 for b in B]
>>> res
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

---

Also, according to your question -

> I would like boolean list of that specifies whether an element of A is equal to an element of B.

If what you really want is a boolean (rather than `1` or `0`) , then you can simply change above examples to -

Example 1 -

```
res = [x in A for x in B]
```

Example 2 -

```
res = [any(a is b for a in A) for b in B]
```

Comment: I think using `any` is unnecessary. See my answer and lmk?

Comment: I don't think you answer is correct, the OP is try to check for every element in `B` , not `A` . And as I already explained, I have given answer, if A and B contain elements that can be compared with `==` , then to use `in` operator. The `any()` is only necessary, if the actual logic is more complex and depends on using `is` rather than `==` .

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks the explanation. Getting 1 and 0 or True and False is the same for me. Mathematically they are exchangable anyway.

Comment: @eli_dink because OP used `is` in his example, rather than `==` . `in` operator works based on `==` not `is` . Both `==` and `is` can return different results, as `is` is identity test (test that both are exactly the same object), whereas `==` is equality test (tests that both objects are equal) . So if the OP's code is complex and depends on using `is` instead of `==` (Though I guess this would be a rare case) , using `in` operator would not work, hence you need the `any()` .

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the *intersection* of the two sets, right?

Here's the intersection of the two sets (which I highly recommend you come up with better names for next time):

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 9]

B = [2, 6, 7]

print [x if x in B else None for x in A]
```

You need the "else" in there or it doesn't work.

And to solve your problem literally:

```
 res = [True if x in A else False for x in B]
```

I recommend you check this answer out: [if/else in Python's list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/python-if-else-in-list-comprehension)

Comment: You can shorten the last code down to `res = [x in B for x in A]`

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I would usually have done that but I was trying to show how the logic worked

Comment: Getting the intersection would've been easy with `set(A) & set(B)`. But I really want a vector/list with 1 and 0 (or true and false)

Comment: @Tim that's what I gave for the final line of my code. Oh well!