# Delete multiple dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have been trying to delete multiple dictionaries in a list but I can only delete one at a time.

Below is the main code I am working on. Records is the list of dictionaries. I want to delete dictionaries that have 0 in them.

```
Records = [{'Name':'Kelvin','Price': 0},{'Name': 'Michael','Price':10}]
```

I want to delete dictionaries with Prices of 0

```
def deleteUnsold(self):
    for d in records:
        for key, value in d.items():
            if d['Price'] == 0:
                records.remove(d)
```

Comment: What does the for-loop `for key, value in d.items()` do?

Comment: its meant to loop through the keys and values in the dictionaries @MrHug

Comment: I can see that, but you use neither `key` nor `value` in the innards of the `for-loop`, making the loop quite useless ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with an `if` condition

```
>>> Records = [{'Name':'Kelvin','Price': 0},{'Name': 'Michael','Price':10}]
>>> [i for i in Records if i['Price'] != 0]
[{'Price': 10, 'Name': 'Michael'}]
```

Check out [if/else in Python's list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/python-if-else-in-list-comprehension) to learn more about using a conditional within a list 
    comprehension.

---

Note that [as mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763208/delete-multiple-dictionaries-in-a-list/34763252?noredirect=1#comment57271724_34763252)] you can also leave out checking for the value `0`. However this also works if `Price` is `None`, hence you may use the first alternative if you are not sure of the data type of the value of `Price`

```
>>> [i for i in Records if i['Price']]
[{'Price': 10, 'Name': 'Michael'}]
```

Comment: You can probably omit the `is not 0` part (and I would've used `!= 0` instead, as I trust equality more than I trust integer interning).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 In a moment

Comment: I am not really conversant with list comprehension. How do I then add the delete statement?

Comment: @MrKay - Read through the provided link on list comprehension.

Comment: Exactly @MrKay You do not need a delete statement when you are using a list comprehension. When you use a list comp you create a new list by selecting a few items from the original iterator. So you are not deleting anything from the original list. As mentioned in the [docs that I have linked in the answer](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), it is a shortened form of writing a loop.

Comment: @BhargavRao Perfectly answered. You must be a lecturer..haha

Comment: @MrKay Read through the documentation clearly and very very slowly. If you don't understand list comps in general refer the [Wikipedia topic on list comprehensions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension)

Comment: @MrKay Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: @BhargavRao It works perfectly fine and I can print out the new list. One last thing, before I call this a wrap. How do I replace the old Records with the new one?

Comment: That's simple `Records = [i for i in Records if i['Price'] != 0]` will do the job..... Also before leaving remember to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) this answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @BhargavRao I know it's that simple, i tried it couple of times, but it gives me this error - local variable 'records' referenced before assignment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100572/discussion-between-mrkay-and-bhargav-rao).

Comment: Strictly speaking, this isn't deleting items, but making a new list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
print filter(lambda x:x['Price']!=0,Records)
```

Comment: It is considered 'less'  pythonic, and list comprehension should be preferred. Also be careful that filter in python 3 returns an iterator and not a list.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, generally speaking you shouldn't remove items from a list you're iterating for, because that will probable make you miss some items of the list.

Now, about some other answer spoken here, yes, they work, but strictly speaking they're not removing/deleting items from the list: they're creating a new list and replacing the old variable with a new list.

What could be done:

```
for d in list(records):
    if d['Price'] == 0:
        records.remove(d)

for d in reversed(records):
    if d['Price'] == 0:
        records.remove(d)

for idx in range(len(records)-1,-1,-1):
    if records[idx]['Price'] == 0:
        records.pop(idx)
```

I like this one, though:

```
for d in records[::-1]:
    if d['Price'] == 0:
        records.remove(d)
```

Comment: Please refer to these two deleted answers http://i.stack.imgur.com/anHx0.png for a complete discussion of your solution. Thanks