# How do you replace integers in a list with a string in python?

Tags: python

For instance, how would I define a function so that every odd integer in a list is replaced with the string 'odd'? Thanks

```
list = [10 , 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,]
```

Intended result

```
[10, 'odd', 12, 'odd', 14, 'odd', 16]
```

Comment: Have you read about loops and conditionals?.

Comment: Note: Please do not name a variable the same as a Python built-in. In this case `list` then masks the built-in function `list(iterator)`

Answer (score 2):

A one line solution can be:

```
print [(i,'odd')[i%2] for i in list]
```

Comment: Reverse the tuple for more clarity: `[(x,'odd')[x%2] for x in list]`

Comment: It is also better to use a tuple `(x,'odd')` rather than a list `[x,'odd'] since the tuple is constructed once and the list each and every time through the loop...

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you should probably get the solution on your own, but anyway...

```
result = []
for i in list:
    if i % 2 != 0:
        result.append('odd')
    else:
        result.append(i)
```

Or, maybe something to push you forward:

```
def turn_odd(i):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        return 'odd'
    else:
        return i

list = [10 , 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,]
result = map(lambda x: turn_odd(x), list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len (list)):
    if (list[i] % 2 != 0):
        list[i] = "odd"
```

Comment: A first argument of 0 to `range` may be omitted.  I.e., one would normally just write `range(len(list))`.

Comment: Okay. I haven't used python in a while. I'll change it now

Comment: It is better to do `for i, x in enumerate(list): if x%2: list[i]='odd'`

Comment: @Reti43  It is not the parity of the index to check -- it is the parity of the object inside. So your code is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
list = [10 , 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
new_list = [i if i % 2 == 0 else "odd" for i in list]
```

Here's a good example of how it works: [if/else in Python's list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/python-if-else-in-list-comprehension)

Comment: Technically this isn't what OP asked for.  OP asked to replace the odd elements of a list, not generate a new list with the odd elements replaced.  Whether this matters to OP or not is unclear, but it does create a new list.

Comment: You could do `list[:] = ...` instead of `new_list = ...`  You shouldn't be using `list` as a variable name anyway because it shadows the built-in type.  You could also do `["odd" if i % 2 else i for i in list]`

Answer (score 0):

First note that `list` is reserved for the type list in Python, so I will use `my_list` instead. Then you have three options:

**A loop with a conditional**

```
for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
    if (i % 2 != 0):
        my_list[i] = "odd"
```

**List comprehension (same logic as above)**

```
my_list = ["odd" if i % 2 != 0 else my_list[i] for i in range(len(my_list))]
```

**A loop without a conditional**

```
for i in range(1, len(my_list), 2):
     my_list[i] = "odd"
```