# conditionally print out lines in python

Tags: python, string, generator

I have a list of strings. I hope to print out the strings in the list that meet a condition. The list is as below:

```
In [5]: L = ["John and Mary", "Leslie", "Iva and Mark Li"]
```

I hope to print out each of the strings in L that has an `and` in it --

```
'John and Mary', 'Iva and Mark Li'
```

I have the following code:

```
In [6]: def grep(pattern, line):
            if pattern in line:
                print line

In [7]: [grep("and", I) for I in L]
```

This returns

```
John and Mary
Iva and Mark Li
Out[7]: [None, None, None]
```

What's the right way to do it? Thank you!!

Comment: [If/else list comprehensions in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension) would probably be a good post for you to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be straight-forward:

```
>>> L = ["John and Mary", "Leslie", "Iva and Mark Li"]
>>> for s in L:
    if ' and ' in s: print(s)


John and Mary
Iva and Mark Li
```

If you want to capture the strings in a list, use a comprehension:

```
>>> [s for s in L if ' and ' in s]
['John and Mary', 'Iva and Mark Li']
```

Answer (score 5):

Because your function does not have a return statement, it always returns `None`. You need to replace `print` with `return`.