# Conditional definition of matrix elements in sage

Tags: python, sage

In Sage, trying to define a matrix with conditions for the cells by:

```
matrix([[(if gcd(i, j) == 0: log(radical((i+j)*i*j)) else: -1.0) for j in srange(1, 5)] for i in srange(1, 5)])
```

I get a syntax error:

```
...
matrix([[(if gcd(i, j) == _sage_const_0 : log(radical((i+j)*i*j)) else: -_sage_const_1p0 ) for j in srange(_sage_const_1 , _sage_const_5 )] for i in srange(_sage_const_1 , _sage_const_5 )])
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the problem here? How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another possibility.

```
sage: f = lambda i, j: log(radical((i + j)*i*j)) if gcd(i,j) == 1 else -1
sage: m = matrix(SR, 4, lambda i, j: f(i + 1, j + 1))
sage: m
[ log(2)  log(6)  log(6) log(10)]
[ log(6)      -1 log(30)      -1]
[ log(6) log(30)      -1 log(42)]
[log(10)      -1 log(42)      -1]
```

This uses a different syntax for matrix initialization, in which we
first specify the base ring, the matrix size, and then a function
of `(i, j)` for coefficients. Note that since Sage indexes rows and
columns from `0`, we have to apply our function to `i + 1` and `j + 1`.

Putting `-1` for non-coprime `(i, j)` might work better than `-1.0`
for exact computations.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a Python one, really, not Sage per se.  Python has some filtering for list comprehensions, but it doesn't look like this.  See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension).

So [let's try it](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdyL0KgCAQAOA96B1uvDMLHRp9kmgQ_zgxBW3o8YPGvvG77N35weMoLWG3np0tiLxkEiwyEXCE5DyyzGSMglBGgFVvCmLrkIErjG5rCqjlTue3_F-apxe-Fx9J&lang=sage):

```
matrix([[log(radical((i+j)*i*j)) if gcd(i,j)==0 else -1.0 for j in srange(1,5)] for i in srange(1,5)])
```

By the way, did you really want `if gcd(i,j)==1`?  Unlikely you'll get a gcd of zero in this one!

Comment: Strange, I have tested so many variants (I'm new to both py and sage), of course it works. And yes its supposed to be ==1. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome - and glad you indeed wanted coprimality!