# if-else in a dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dict-comprehension

Is it possible to use the `else` statement (and if yes, how?) in a `dictcomp`?

It is not possible to use `else` as part of the comprehension itself (see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)) but at least in `list` and `set` comprehensions it is possible to use the `conditional_expression` (see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)).

An example for `listcomp` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension#4260304).

My example code is:

```
converters = {"id": int}
rows = [{"id": "1", "name": "foo"}, {"id": "2", "name": "bar"}]
for row in rows:
    row = {k: converters[k](v) if k in converters else k:v for k,v in row.items()}
    print(row)
```

This does not work.

The weird part is that

`row = {k: converters[k](v) if k in converters for k, v in row.items()}` does not work either, although it should be ok.

`row = {k: converters[k](v) for k, v in row.items() if k in converters}` does work,but this is not the result I want.
`row = {k: converters[k](v) for k, v in row.items() if k in converters else k:v}` should not work, as I pointed out above.

I know that I could bypass the problem by using two dictcomps, but I want to know why this does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the conditional applies for the value of the dictionary, not for the key value pair, i.e it is evaluated as:

```
row = {k: (converters[k](v) if k in converters else k:v) for k,v in row.items()}
```

and `k:v` is not syntactically valid here, it's only valid inside a pair of curly brackets or in a function signature (so, you could place `k:v` in brackets and fix the `SyntaxError` but, that changes the end result).

The solution is to simply supply the value in the conditional since that is what changes:

```
row = {k: converters[k](v) if k in converters else v for k,v in row.items()}
```

Another option, of course, is to instead supply tuples to the `dict` constructor:

```
row = dict((k, converters[k](v)) if k in converters else (k,v) for k,v in row.items())
```