# Python list comprehension: assigning values in if else statement

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a List comprehension for below for loop in python

```
num_list = []

for num in range(10):
if num % 2 == 0:
    num_list.append('EVEN')
else:
    num_list.append('ODD')
```

I wrote something like

```
[num if num % 2 == 0  'EVEN' else 'ODD' for num in range(10)]
```

and

```
[num if num % 2 == 0  then 'EVEN' else 'ODD' for num in range(10)]
```

but both are giving syntax errors and not valid.

I am new to pyhton, so not sure if this can be translated to a comprehension or not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if/else in Python's list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternary expressions work slightly differently:

```
['EVEN' if num % 2 == 0 else 'ODD' for num in range(10)]
```

although I think

```
['ODD' if num % 2 else 'EVEN' for num in range(10)]
```

looks nicer.

Think of it this way:

```
[('ODD' if num % 2 else 'EVEN') for num in range(10)]
```

The brackets can be used for clarification, but they are not necessary and might confuse people into thinking you're building tuples or a generator expression.

Comment: Thank you Tim!. I was looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
>>> ['EVEN' if num%2 == 0 else 'ODD' for num in range(10)]
```

#driver values

```
OUT : ['EVEN', 'ODD', 'EVEN', 'ODD', 'EVEN', 'ODD', 'EVEN', 'ODD', 'EVEN', 'ODD']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
['EVEN' if num % 2 == 0 else 'ODD' for num in range(10)]
```

so ideally what we need to return or push into list is from where the list comprehension starts. Let's try to build it from your for loop -

```
num_list = []

for num in range(10):            #  for num in range(10) (third part)
    if num % 2 == 0:
        num_list.append('EVEN')  # 'EVEN' if num % 2 == 0 (first part)
    else:
        num_list.append('ODD')   #  else 'ODD' (second part)
```

You could take a look at [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/python-tutorial-list-comprehension-examples/) to understand list comprehension more.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know which number is even or odd then you try this

```
print([str(nub) + ' Odd' if nub % 2 != 0 else str(nub) + ' Even' for nub in range(1, 11)])
```

Output:['1 Odd', '2 Even', '3 Odd', '4 Even', '5 Odd', '6 Even', '7 Odd', '8 Even', '9 Odd', '10 Even']