# How to change each character to the one before it in a string and maintain the original order python?

Tags: python, file

I am facing a problem with my code, and I cant think of a way to fix it.

*Note: I am not allowed to use import in my code*

*the code goes as follows:*

```html
def decode(in_file, out_file):
    try:
        s = ""
        chr_nums = []
        splitlst = []
        lines = []
        lst = []
        f = open('q4.txt','r')
        for line in f:
            lines = line.split()
            for i in range(len(lines)):
                b = str(lines[i])
                for l in b:
                    chr_nums = chr(ord(l) - 1)
                    for a in chr_nums:
                        c =' '.join(a)
                        print c 

                    
    except IOError:
        print "Cant decipher' {"+in_file+"} 'due to an IO Error."
        f.close()
```

The goal with this code is to replace each letter in every word to the letter before it.
i.e: a is changed to z and so on.

*The code has to change a file that contains this kind of text:*

```html
Uif Xiffmt po uif cvt hp spvoe boe spvoe
Uif Xiffmt po uif cvt hp spvoe boe spvoe
```

*to this result:*

```html
The Wheels on the bus go round and round
The Wheels on the bus go round and round
```

*this is what my for loop prints in the out_file:*

```html
T h e W h e e l s o n t h e b u s g o r o u n d a n d r o u n dT h e W h e e l s o n t h e b u s g o r o u n d a n d r o u n d
```

How can I get the result that I showed in the example?
How can I re-join the characters to form the original order?

*note2: I did try to use join, but no luck using that as well*

*note3: the file the code gets doesn't necessarily contain the same sentence twice.*

Comment: "I am facing problems". What problems are they? Your output looks quite nice, doesn't it? Maybe use `"".join` instead of `" ".join` to get rid of the spaces.

Comment: join doesnt give me the result i am looking for, as i stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `if/else in Python's list comprehension` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension).

example code is

```
f = open('q4.txt','r')
for line in f:
    lst = list(line)
    lst2 = [chr(ord(x) - 1)  if x != ' ' else ' ' for x in lst]
    print("".join(lst2))
```

I got the following output

```
The Wheels on the bus go round and round    
The Wheels on the bus go round and round
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help! um but the thing is when i try to write the result onto a file it only prints one line when it is supposed to print as many as the original file,I am wondering if you can help me with that as well?

Comment: open the file in `a` (append) mode as described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) and instead of printing into console, use `out.write("".join(lst2))`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Prince Francis code, here is a solution that adopts your style of code:

```
def decode(foo):
    final_string = ""
    f = foo
    for line in f:
        lines = line.split()
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            b = str(lines[i])
            for l in b:
                chr_nums = chr(ord(l) - 1)
                final_string += chr_nums
            final_string += " "
        final_string += "\n" # new line
    return(final_string)

secret_text = ["Uif Xiffmt po uif cvt hp spvoe boe spvoe", 
               "Uif Xiffmt po uif cvt hp spvoe boe spvoe"]

print(decode(foo=secret_text))
```

Note how the first five lines after "try" are not needed at all. They have no impact. The rest is just setting spaces and the new-line-character when appropriate.

Comment: I dont understand what is the use for 'secret_text', is the secret text the same as the orginal file?

Comment: Yes, it is. I replaced the file (which I don't have) by the content you told us.