# Python: Proper use of any() to check if one value of one array exists in another array?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, any

In Python, I am trying to create an if statement that proceeds if one variable of one array exists somewhere in another list or array. Here is my basic code, which is supposed to check if any of the values within `ids` exist in `follow_num`:

```
ids = [123,321,111,333]
follow_num = [111, 222]

if any(ids == follow_num):
    print(ids)
```

Despite my best attempts, and many versions of the above, I cannot get this to work. Could someone please elaborate where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must loop through each value in `ids` and check if `any` of those values exist in `follow_num`. Use `any` with a generator comprehension:

```
if any(i in follow_num for i in ids):
    print(ids)
```

Output:

```
[123,321,111,333]
```

Edit:

If you want to print any matches `any()` doesn't work, you must use a for loop since `any()` computes for the entire list. Example:

```
for i in ids:
    if i in follow_num: print(i)
```

Note that you can speed up both of these operations by converting `follow_num` beforehand to a `set()` by doing `follow_num = set(follow_num)`. This is faster because `set` has an `O(1)` in operation, compared to lists which compute `in` in `O(N)`.

Comment: Quick question, is there an obvious way to make the if statement within the for loop a list comprehension?

Comment: You can do something like `[print(i) for i in ids if i in follow_num]`, but that defeats the purpose of the list comprehension - you're using it to print values not to build a list.

Comment: A good resource for conditionals in list comprehensions would be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension

Comment: Thanks for all the help and the reference.

Comment: @Coolio2654 happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can compare two sets:

```
ids = [123, 321, 111, 333]
follow_num = [111, 222]

matches = list(set(ids) & set(follow_num))

print(matches)
# [111]

print(bool(matches))
# True
```

Comment: I would wonder what the speed of this method is, hmm, but it looks interesting.

Comment: @Coolio2654 It scales much better than the answer by Primusa in its current form. However if `ids` was converted to a `set` first in the answer by Primusa it would scale well too. Darius should keep in mind the conversion of `matches` to `list(...)` is useless

Comment: Also, `any(matches)` is wrong, because `any([0])` is `False` and `0` could be a valid `id`. You should simply just check `if matches` or `print bool(matches)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ids = [123,321,111,333]
>>> follow_num = [111, 222]
>>> if set(ids).intersection(follow_num): 
...   print(ids)
... 
[123, 321, 111, 333]
```

Comment: It might be helpful to the OP if you add some explanation to what you code does.