# Using 'else np.nan' in list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list of websites, and I want to extract social media profiles only (let's say facebook, linkedin and pinterest)

```
import numpy as np

mylist = ['linkedin.com/profilexyz','facebook.com/profile374','bbcnews.com/USA_news','stackoverflow.com']
```

I have used list comprehension to get the urls, returning `nan` if it's not found:

```
facebook = [x for x in mylist if 'facebook' in x else np.nan for x in mylist]
linkedin = [x for x in mylist if 'linkedin' in x else np.nan for x in mylist]
pinterest = [x for x in mylist if 'pinterest' in x else np.nan for x in mylist]
```

However I get the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-329-578130619ae7>", line 1
facebook = [x for x in mylist if 'facebook' in x else np.nan for x in mylist]
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have checked the suggested duplicates such as this one: [if/else in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension) but can't get my comprehension to work.

Answer (score 1):

you have the order messed up and an extra for

```
fb = [x if 'facebook' in x else np.nan for x in mylist]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to just have the successful result in the list? Like `[facebook.com/profile374]` instead of  `[nan, 'facebook.com/profile374', nan, nan]`. For pinterest this is not found so the result is also `['nan,nan,nan,nan]`. How could I make a single `nan` if nothing is found?

Comment: @SCool `fb = [i for i in mylist if 'facebook' in i] or [np.nan]` (if you want a list with a single entry if it isn't in the list)

Comment: see Rakesh's answer for this..basically just dropping the else

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `collections.defaultdict` and `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
mylist = ['linkedin.com/profilexyz','facebook.com/profile374','bbcnews.com/USA_news','stackoverflow.com']

for url in mylist:
    result[url.split('/')[0]].append(url)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'linkedin.com': ['linkedin.com/profilexyz'], 'facebook.com': ['facebook.com/profile374'], 'bbcnews.com': ['bbcnews.com/USA_news'], 'stackoverflow.com': ['stackoverflow.com']})
```

---

FYI in your method

```
facebook = [x for x in mylist if 'facebook' in x]
print(facebook)
```

Comment: your FYI only returns the results that contain the url name..the OP wants np.nan where there aren't matches, i.e. result list same size as original

Comment: @DerekEden. Ok ..I do not see that condition in OP's request

Comment: I guess it didn't specifically stipulate the condition, but based on their attempt it looked like that's what they wanted

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra for loop from list comprehension.

**Ex.**

```
import numpy as np

mylist = ['linkedin.com/profilexyz','facebook.com/profile374','bbcnews.com/USA_news','stackoverflow.com']
facebook = [x if 'facebook' in x else np.nan for x in mylist]
linkedin = [x if 'linkedin' in x else np.nan for x in mylist]
pinterest = [x if 'pinterest' in x else np.nan for x in mylist]
print(facebook)
print(linkedin)
print(pinterest)
```

**O/P:**

```
[nan, 'facebook.com/profile374', nan, nan]
['linkedin.com/profilexyz', nan, nan, nan]
[nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

Remove duplicate `nan` value from list using [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

```
print(list(set(facebook)))
print(list(set(linkedin)))
print(list(set(pinterest)))
```

O/P:

```
[nan, 'facebook.com/profile374']
[nan, 'linkedin.com/profilexyz']
[nan]
```

Comment: ok, thanks. Is there a way to just keep the values we find, rather than repeating `nan, nan, nan` ? I tried already to just have a single `nan` if not found,  but it doesn't work: `[x if 'facebook' in x else np.nan]`

Comment: @SCool Yes you can, remove else condition and re-write list comprehension like this eg. `[x for x in mylist if 'facebook' in x ]` .

Comment: @SCool You want to keep single `nan` value in the list not duplicate `nan` value. `list comprehension` does not support to check where the list contains element or not. In that case, you should try normal `for loop` and do something that you want.

Comment: @SCool Updated answer, how to remove a duplicate element from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just use parentheses:

```
facebook = [(x for x in mylist) if 'facebook' in x else np.nan for x in mylist]
linkedin = [(x for x in mylist) if 'linkedin' in x else np.nan for x in mylist]
pinterest = [(x for x in mylist) if 'pinterest' in x else np.nan for x in mylist]
```