# How to use "continue" in single line if esle within a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop, continue

I have a for loop and within that there is a simple single line if condition.
I want to use continue option in the else part.

This does not work :

```py
def defA() : 
    return "yes"
flag = False
for x in range(4) : 
    value = defA() if flag else continue
```

```
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Working code :

```py
for x in range(4) : 
    if flag : 
        defA()
    else : 
        continue
```

Comment: `X if C else Y` is an expression. `continue` is a statements. Expressions in Python cannot contain statements. Transform your `if` expression into an `if` statement to fix.

Comment: Ternary operator allow you to assign a variable to A if match condition else B. That's mean B should be a variable or value instead of a Python keyword (`continue`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as a single line if condition in Python. What you have in your first example is a [ternary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator).

You are trying to assign `continue` to a variable named `value`, which does not make any sense, hence the syntax error.

Comment: what about `if i == 2: continue`

Comment: @punkrockpolly It's a normal `if` statement, compressed into one line (which is bad style in Python world).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can you continue statment in a single line as shown below. Let me know if you face some issue

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    if i == 2: continue
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in range(4) : 
    if not flag: continue
    defA()
```

That's how I would do it. I like this guard-clause style pattern so the reader knows if there's no flag, there's other logic to worry about below and it avoids the extra indent.

Answer (score 1):

Can you kindly explain a bit as what you are trying to achieve may be experts can suggest you a better alternative. To me it doesn't make sense to add **else** here because you are only adding **else** to continue-on, which will happen in anycase after the if condition.

In any case, if I get it right, what you are looking for is a [**list comprehension**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension). Here is a working example of how to use it,

```
def defA() :
    return "yes"

flag = True

value = [defA() if flag else 'No' for x in range(4)]  #If you need to use else
value = [defA() for x in range(4) if flag]            #If there is no need for else
```

Comment: True, but it is safe to assume that this is an excerpt from the actual code, therefore we don't know if there are more lines after the `if` clause within the `for` loop.

Comment: Agree, hence I first suggested him to explain the problem first rather discussing his solution. Just a suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Python uses indent for control structures.  What you want to do is not possible in python.

Comment: This is not exactly correct, nor answers the question. You can write, for example `if flag: foo()`. Note the lack of indentation in the control structure.

Comment: @Selcuk your answer was undoubtedly better, but my answer is still literally accurate.  Python does use indent for control structures - and - what he wanted to do is not possible in Python.  I did not intend to convey that there is no possible way to skip an indent occasionally like my favorite `if DE:BUG(...)` statement :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
filtered_array = [x for x in array if x > 3]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).