# Understanding this if statement in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

In the following code,

```
splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
deletes    = [L + R[1:]               for L, R in splits if R]
```

for a given word, what does the `if R` mean in the last list comprehension?

Return `L+R[1:]` for every `L,R` combination in `splits` if R what? Exists? Is that a necessary check?

Comment: If R is not empty.

Comment: `if [1,2,3,4]` evaluates to `True`, `if []` evaluates to `False`

Comment: In the case where `i` is at its maximum value, `L` will be the entire word, and `R` will be empty.  If this wasn't special-cased, `L + R[1:]` would be the entire word, and not the word with a character deleted as all of the other elements of `deletes` are.

Comment: And anyway [pep 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) does not recommend to write an expression with that spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression following `if` is evaluated in a boolean context, and the current value from `splits` is only used if that evaluation is true. In the case of a list, empty lists are considered `False`, all others `True`. The comprehension is equivalent to

```
deletes = []
for L, R in splits:
    if R != []:
        deletes.append(L + R[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

you can have a look (assume that your word is a string):

```
word = 'my_word'
print([(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)])
```

output:

```
[('', 'my_word'),
 ('m', 'y_word'),
 ('my', '_word'),
 ('my_', 'word'),
 ('my_w', 'ord'),
 ('my_wo', 'rd'),
 ('my_wor', 'd'),
 ('my_word', '')]
```

you can see that your last element has an empty string if you do not check for your R since you are using slicing(R[1:]), you will get: `IndexError: string index out of range`, so yes it is necessary to check in this case

`if R` is the way the checking is happing inside the list comprehension, the same logic as in a normal if statement.

you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension) to read more about if/else inside list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I did not understand your questions but I think this would help you understand the Python comprehension syntax. 
You can place your if before 'for' keyword or after it.
1) Case 1: if is before 'for' statement.
Use this syntax if you want to put one element per each loop iteration. You use this to change value calculation method.

```
list_variable = [VALUE_CASE_TRUE if STATEMENT else VALUE_VASE_FALSE for LOOP_VALUE in VALUES_RANGE] # pseudocode here
# Example duplicate even values, but put odd values unchanged:
case_1 = [i if i&1 else 2*i for i in range(10)] # check this out, I bet you would get the point
# you CANNOT do like that though, else is MANDATORY:
case_1 = [i if i&1 for i in range(10)] # invalid syntax
```

2) Case 2: if is after 'for' keyword.
Use this syntax if you want to put value only under some condition.

```
list_variable = [VALUE for LOOP_VALUE in VALUES_RANGE if STATEMENT] # pseudocode here
# Example place only odd values into the new list:
case_2 = [i for i in range(10) if i&1]
```