# Only show tuples in a list where the second item is not empty

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like so below:

```
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/rac/', '0.9.0'), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/racingpost/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/trading_horseracing/', '')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/rac/', '0.9.0'), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/racingpost/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/trading_horseracing/', '')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/International/', ''), ('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/ios/', '1.3.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/ios/', '1.3.0')]
```

What I want to do is only print the tuple where the second item is not blank

So the output would appear like so:

```
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/rac/', '0.9.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/rac/', '0.9.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/apache_gaming/', '5.6.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/ios/', '1.3.0')]
[('/home/david/Git_Stuff/ios/', '1.3.0')]
```

I have tried using an if statement where an item is not blank and using LEN to make sure string length is higher than 0 but this will only take affect on the first tuple in the list and if I tried this again on the second tuple it would return out of range where there is only one.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: So you have a list of list? What about your code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension :

[if/else in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

in your case :

```
strippedList = [x for x in list if x[1] != '']
```

Answer (score 1):

Restrict your lists like this

```
a = [('toto',''), ('babar', 'x') , ('ursule','')]
b = [_ for _ in a if _[1]] # b is now [('babar', 'x')]
```