# split string if it contain comma, else return string using list comprehension

Tags: python, string, split, list-comprehension

```
#sample input 
dict_ = {'country': {'0': 'a,b,c','1': 'xyz'}}

country_name = []
for country in dict_['country'].values():
    if ',' in country:
        country_name.append(country.split(','))
    else:
       country_name.append([country])
#op of above code
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['xyz']]
```

how to write above code using list comprehension, so far i have tried the below. .I need to add else condition in these list comprehension

```
[x.split(',') for x in dict_['country'].values() if ',' in x]
```

expected output using list comprehension

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['xyz']]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if/else in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the values that do not contain a comma are unused, so you need an `else`

```
[x.split(',') if ',' in x else [x] for x in dict_['country'].values()]
```

**But specific case here** : using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) always returns a `list`.If the delimiter is not present in the original text, you'll just get an list with 1 element,

```
>>> "a,b,c".split(',')
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> "abc".split(',')
['abc']
>>> "a,b,c".split(',', 1) # maxsplit param
['a', 'b,c']
```

You can use that to remove the condition

```
[x.split(',') for x in dict_['country'].values()]
```

---

Your original code is just :

```
country_name = []
for country in dict_['country'].values():
    country_name.append(country.split(','))
```