# Please help me solve this basic python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
## Example - Find the indices in a list where the item is a multiple of 7
def multiple_7(l):
  indices_7 = []
  for i in range(len(l)):
    if(i%7 == 0):
      indices_7 += [i]
  return indices_7 ## list of all indices where the item is a multiple of 7

l = [2, 3, 7, 4, 14, 9] ## multiple_7 should return [2, 4]

print(multiple_7(l))
```

I get output [0] which is obviously not right...

Comment: Just revise what you are doing here: `if(i%7 == 0):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the *i-th* element inside `l` not the index number `i` itself:

```
def multiple_7(l):
    indices_7 = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i] % 7 == 0:            # <---fixed here
            indices_7.append(i) 
    return indices_7 ## list of all indices where the item is a multiple of 7

l = [2, 3, 7, 4, 14, 9]  

print(multiple_7(l))
```

Output:

```
[2,4]
```

You can also shorten your code to:

```
def multiple_7(l):
    return [i for i,v in enumerate(l) if v%7==0]
```

Any time you need the index (and value) of something in a list, use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Read more about list comprehensions with condition here: [if/else in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)