# How to resolve list comprehension syntax error?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
my_string = test
def func_2(my_string):
    return [i+"*" for i in my_string if i!=my_string[len(my_string) - 1] else i]
print(func_2(my_string.copy()))
```

In the above code snippet, I need to use list comprehension to append the characters of my name with a '*'. For example, in the above example, the expected result is t*e*s*t

But, I am getting "invalid syntax" as the error. Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `[i+"*" if i!=my_string[len(my_string) - 1] else i for i in my_string ]`? Please see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: there is no `else` in the filtering clause. If you need ot use a conditional expression, put it in the main part

Comment: Remove the else extension

Comment: The answer bellow in good also note that you can refer to the last element in a list with index -1 and you can add a character to a variable nicely with fstrings: `[f"{c}*" if c != s[-1] else c for c in s]`

Answer (score 1):

You've switched the location of the `for` and `if-else`; The `if-else` should come before the `for` *when* there is an `else`. If there is no `else`, your code would be perfect. Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
def func_2(my_string):
    return [i+"*" if i!=my_string[len(my_string) - 1] else i for i in my_string]
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260304/11059315) for more details on the syntax and use.