# How to deal with variable number of columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In the dataframe I have there are so many columns of which I only need a few. For instance

```
Col_A      Col_B      Col_C      Col_D      Col_E      Col_F
...        ...        ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
```

I only need columns `Col_A, Col_C and Col_E` so currently what I do is `df = df[['Col_A', 'Col_C', 'Col_E']]` but the issue here is that not always there will columns `A, C and E` maybe all these wont be present. So I need if `Col_A` is in `df.columns` add to the df and so on. Is there any simple method to do this ? rather than so many `if`? Now if a Column is missing I get a `KeyError: "['Col_C'] not in index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
df[df.columns.intersection(['Col_A','Col_A','Col_E'], sort=False)]
```

Comment: This is way faster than other answers. Can this be used in groupby like ```df.groupby(by=[df.columns.intersection(['Col_A','Col_A','Col_E'], as_index=False)``` ?

Comment: @Derik81 - Very similar, like `df.groupby(by=df.columns.intersection(['Col_A','Col_A','Col_E']), as_index=False)`

Comment: I think there is some issue by using this. it gives a ```ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length```. When I checked the result of ```df.columns.intersection(['Col_A','Col_A','Col_E'])``` it prints as ```Index(['Col_A','Col_A','Col_E'], dtype='object')```. It has no issue when I do ```.groupby(by=['Col_A','Col_A','Col_E']``` but when I input as you gave it throws an error.

Comment: @Derik81 - I forget, need convert to list `df.groupby(by=df.columns.intersection(['Col_A','Col_A','Col_E']).tolist(), as_index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html)

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(['a','b','c'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260304/3888719). For example:

```py
test_columns = ['Col_A', 'Col_C', 'Col_E']
df = df[[c for c in test_columns if c in df.columns]]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have interpreted, you could create a copy of `df`, store it in another variable and then 'drop' the columns you don't require,

```
df_copy = df.copy()
df = df.drop(['Col_A', 'Col_C', 'Col_E'], axis = 1)

# If you want to add other columns to the df
df['Col_B'] = df_copy['Col_B']
```