# How can I expand this list comprehension into a multi-line for loop?

Tags: python, ternary

I am trying to un condense:

```
samp_neighs = [_set(_sample(to_neigh, 
                            num_sample,
                            )) if len(to_neigh) >= num_sample else to_neigh for to_neigh in to_neighs]
```

into multiple lines.  Can someone help?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking for an automatic formatting tool?

Comment: Show us what you tried, and which specific problem you hit when doing it yourself. In general, we don't write or translate code for you, _or_ explain code that's provided unless given a very specific description of which aspect of that code requires explanation; that can include building a [mre] that factors out all the aspects of the code that you _do_ already understand, and which thus don't require explanation.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59128169/1456253

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I wrote out your code in a few lines rather than a single line it would look something like this:

```
result = []

for to_neigh in to_neighs:
    if len(to_neigh) >= num_sample:
        result.append(_set(_sample(to_neigh, num_sample)))
    else:
        result.append(to_neigh)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Is the original code faster or just more compact?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is simply improve readability (since there is no other benefit of writing a for loop), you can extract `_set(...) if .. else ..` to its own function rather than shove it into a list comprehension

For example

```
def foo(to_neigh, num_sample):
    s = _sample(to_neigh, num_sample,)
    return _set(s) if len(to_neigh) >= num_sample else to_neigh
```

Then you can map that function over the list

```
num_sample = ...
samp_neighs = list(map(lambda n: foo(n, num_sample), to_neighs))
```

Comment: I like your answer. It's not exactly what OP asked for but I think it's elegant if it needs to be reused.
To answer the question specifically you could "uncondense" the return statement in foo