# Access worksheet inside the spreadsheet using URL and worksheet ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'll try to be straight forward into this.

I've got a spreadsheet URL like this: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1231SDFS3afer3SDfsdf-34SDFSDgfdsd42/edit#gid=5439787534`

where the part `gid=5439787534` points to the exact sheet inside the spreadsheet I want to access. I'm using python + gspred to access it, but I'm not finding a way to get to the GID I stated above.

My code is like this for now:

```
wb = client.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1231SDFS3afer3SDfsdf-34SDFSDgfdsd42/edit#gid=5439787534')
```

But it doesn't access the sheet, it just access the spreadsheet in general, not accessing the exact tab I need..

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to retrieve the worksheet using the sheet ID (`gid`) using gspread of python.
- You have already bee able to get and put values using Sheets API.

Unfortunately, it seems that there are no methods for directly retrieving the worksheet from the sheet ID in gspread. So in this case, I would like to propose a script for achieving your goal.

#### Sample script:

In this script, the script of authorization is not shown. So please use your script for it. And please set the variables of `spreadsheetId` and `sheetId`.

```
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetId = 12345 # Please set the sheet ID (the value of "gid")

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheets = [s for s in spreadsheet.worksheets() if s.id == sheetId]
if sheets:
    sheet = sheets[0]
    values = sheet.get_all_values()
    print(values)
```

- When your Spreadsheet URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1231SDFS3afer3SDfsdf-34SDFSDgfdsd42/edit#gid=5439787534` is used, the Spreadsheet ID and sheet ID are `1231SDFS3afer3SDfsdf-34SDFSDgfdsd42` and `5439787534`, respectively.
- When above script is run, when the sheet of `sheetId` is included in the Spreadsheet, the values are returned.

#### Reference:

- [Selecting a Worksheet of gspread](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#selecting-a-worksheet)

Comment: Could you explain the logic of
`sheets = [s for s in spreadsheet.worksheets() if s.id == sheetId}`

and also it's return content

Thanks

Comment: @João Casarin Thank you for replying. About `sheets = [s for s in spreadsheet.worksheets() if s.id == sheetId]`, this is the list comprehension. In this case, the sheet object is retrieved from all sheet objects using the inputted `sheetId`. When the sheet object of `sheetId` is found, the object is put in the list. I think that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4260280) will help to understand about it. If my answer was not useful for your situation, please tell me. At that time, I apologize and I would like to modify it.

Comment: Hmmm, list comprehension is actually a new thing for me, I haven't even saw this on my graduation... I think this is the problem, neither the thread you stated could help, I think I'll need to study it deeper, because I don't understand the part `[s for s in...]`

Also, congrats for the way of handling the sheetId, I haven't thought of doing that... That worked perfectly!

Thanks buddy!

Comment: I'm sorry for this, but is it possible to you trying to help me on my other issue? It's also about python + gspread, but now it's about handling merged cells. If necessary, I can post the link here

Comment: @João Casarin Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, when you posted it, can you show the URL of the question? I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Sure I can! I'm glad you're interested onto this :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901345/get-combined-merged-cells-value
this is the post!

Comment: @João Casarin Thank you for replying. I will check it.