# Get combined/merged cells value

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm coding a new python script that need to extract data from google sheets, but there are many cells which are merged/combined, and only the top-left cell from this merge has the value. It's important to have that value on all the merged cells.

How can I do that?

Python 3.8.5 + gspread 3.6.0

**Note: every comment "trying to get...", the code right below it should return the same value as the previous code.**

**Spreadsheet test:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Dyxufu1y1ouBCPkf5Y7Vt1UW70WroK0Moy_DD7bZKc/edit?usp=sharing

Code for reproducing the problem:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import os
import pprint

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
secret = os.path.join(here, 'credentials.json')

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(secret, scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open_by_key('17Dyxufu1y1ouBCPkf5Y7Vt1UW70WroK0Moy_DD7bZKc')
ws = sheet.sheet1
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

#getting the FIRST text
result = ws.acell('A1')
pp.pprint('A1: '+result.value)

#trying to get the SAME text on the cell col+1
result = ws.acell('A2')
pp.pprint('A2: '+result.value)

#getting the 'simple_cell'
result = ws.acell('C2')
pp.pprint('C2: '+result.value)

#getting the 'row_merged'
result = ws.acell('D2')
pp.pprint('D2: '+result.value)

#trying to get 'row_merged' on row+1
result = ws.acell('E2')
pp.pprint('E2: '+result.value)

#getting the 'col_merged'
result = ws.acell('D6')
pp.pprint('D6: '+result.value)

#trying to get 'col_merged' on col+1
result = ws.acell('D7')
pp.pprint('D7: '+result.value)
```

The output is like this:

```
('A1: just to confirm, the value "row_merged" has been put to cell D2 originally. Value "col_merged" is in D6 initially. Since it's merged, the expected result should be found on all merged cells')
'A2: '
'C2: simple cell'
'D2: row_merged'
'E2: '
'D6: col_merged'
'D7: '
PS C:\Users\joaov\Desktop>
```

The point is: A2 must be equals to A1... E2=D2, D7==D6... But it seems there's no way of handling merged cells with gspread.

Comment: Is there any chance you could post a [mre]?

Comment: @RandomDavis sure

the test spreadsheet is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Dyxufu1y1ouBCPkf5Y7Vt1UW70WroK0Moy_DD7bZKc/edit#gid=0

the code is: https://hastebin.com/umuvecajir.apache

output: https://hastebin.com/wuliqihasa.rust

Note: every comment "trying to get...", the code right below it should return the same value as the previous code.

Comment: I should clarify that your example should be self-contained, i.e. not hosted on an external site like you have. Same goes for the output, it has to be in your question itself. It should be some Python code that we can paste into an IDE, run it, and see the issue. If you have to fake or "mock" any incoming data, that's fine, as long as it shows us the same issue. I recommend taking the [tour] to get a better idea of the format this site wants questions to be in.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, @RandomDavis , I didn't think of editing my main question with the codes and etc.. I'm just gonna edit it right now, I hope you can help me with the issue :)

Comment: That's good, since I or someone else might be able to help in that case.

Comment: Just finished editing, now it really seems really better to understand.. My apologies.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can I ask you about the output you expect? Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `every comment "trying to get...", the code right below it should return the same value as the previous code.`. 2. I cannot open your shared Spreadsheet. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: You can always ask anything :D
1. Well, you can see that there are "blocks" in the code, and each block has a "pp.pprint" to show in the console the output. On the blocks that have the comment starting with "trying to get...", these blocks needs to return the same thing as the previous block, or it should. That's the merge cell problem.

2. I'm sorry for that, I forgot to share the spreadsheet with everyone, you can try again, it should open.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the merged cells using gspread of python.

In your sample Spreadsheet, for example, the cells "A1:L12" are merged. Under this condition, when the values are retrieved from the merged cells of "A1:L12" using Sheets API, `just to confirm, the value "row_merged" has been put to cell D2 originally. Value "col_merged" is in D6 initially. Since it's merged, the expected result should be found on all merged cells` is retrieved only cell "A1". So in order to retrieve the same values from all cells of "A1:L12", it is required to put the values to the cells "A2:L12". Unfortunately, it seems that there are no methods for directly achieving this situation in Sheets API. So, in this answer, I would like to propose this using a script.

By the way, about `result = ws.acell('A2')` in your script, this cell is not merged and it's empty. So in this case, I think that the empty value is correct. I thought that you might have wanted to check the cell "B1". In this answer, this is also considered.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheet_id = '###'  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'  # Please set the sheet name.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
access_token = client.auth.token
url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + \
    spreadsheet_id + "?fields=sheets&ranges=" + sheet_name
res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token})
obj = res.json()
# print(obj['sheets'][0]['merges'])

sheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
ws = sheet.worksheet(sheet_name)

# 1. All values are retrieved.
values = ws.get_all_values()

# 2. Put the values to the merged cells.
if 'merges' in obj['sheets'][0].keys():
    for e in obj['sheets'][0]['merges']:
        value = values[e['startRowIndex']][e['startColumnIndex']]
        rows = len(values)
        if rows < e['endRowIndex']:
            for i in range(0, e['endRowIndex'] - rows):
                values.append([''])
        for r in range(e['startRowIndex'], e['endRowIndex']):
            cols = len(values[r])
            if cols < e['endColumnIndex']:
                values[r].extend([''] * (e['endColumnIndex'] - cols))
            for c in range(e['startColumnIndex'], e['endColumnIndex']):
                values[r][c] = value

# For A1
print('A1: '+values[0][0])

# For B1
# output: just to confirm, the value "row_merged" has been put to cell D2 originally. Value "col_merged" is in D6 initially. Since it's merged, the expected result should be found on all merged cells
print('B1: '+values[0][1])

# For C2
# output: simple cell
print('C2: '+values[1][2])

# For D2
# output: row_merged
print('D2: '+values[1][3])

# For E2
# output: row_merged
print('E2: '+values[1][4])

# For D6
# output: col_merged
print('D6: '+values[5][3])

# For D7
# output: col_merged
print('D7: '+values[6][3])
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the method of "spreadsheets.get" in Sheets API is used with `requests` using the access token retrieved from `client = gspread.authorize(credentials)` of gspread.
- In this sample script, the values are processed in the list. So when you retrieved the values from the merged cells, please retrieve them from the list `values`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: Thanks in advance for your help! But could I ask something?
On your explanation, you meant `A1:L1` instead of `A1:A12`, right? And also, analyzing the script, it seems I would need to get the merge range URL right? It's not viable needing to get this url everytime :/

Comment: Also, this feature will be implemented with the other issue you helped me, to open the worksheet by its GID

Comment: @João Casarin Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. If my answer was not useful for your situation, could you please tell me about the detail of it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Don't worry about the english, it's perfectly fine, I also don't speak english natively.
You said that in my spreadsheet there is a merge in the range `A1:A12`, but it's actually `A1:L1`, right?

And analyzing your script, I think I'll need to get the merged cells URL, will I? Just like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Dyxufu1y1ouBCPkf5Y7Vt1UW70WroK0Moy_DD7bZKc/edit#gid=0&range=D6:D8

If yes, this would be difficult, since it should not be an input, got it?

Comment: @João Casarin Thank you for replying. Yes. I misunderstood it. I apologize for this. That is "A1:L12". So I updated my answer. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `And analyzing your script, I think I'll need to get the merged cells URL, will I?`. In above sample script, the URL includes the Spreadsheet ID and sheet name. When the merged cells are found, the values are retrieved.

Comment: @João Casarin For the sheet which doesn't include the merged cells, I updated my sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Hello, your sample script really works, and again, thanks for that! However, as you helped me on other post, we need to assume the only input I have is the worksheet ID... The user theoretically does not know the worksheet name (in your sample script that would be the `sheet_name` variable.

Comment: I tried to implement your sample script of getting the worksheet by its ID with this sample script, but the variable `url` seems to use the worksheet NAME. Can it be changed?

Comment: Well, I figured out that a worksheet object has the attribute `title`, so with that I can use both your codes. It seems to be working perfectly!

For now, I can't confirm with my official code with the official spreadsheet because I can't access it right now. So, I won't finish this post yet, I'll need to do that by monday, okay?

Comment: @João Casarin Thank you for replying. If my answer didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: yeah, apparently it's working fine! I appreciate your effort for helping me, thanks!
Have a good day!

Comment: @João Casarin Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.