# Building a dictionary with lists as values using list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm trying to simplify the following code using **list/dict comprehension**, in which I want to build a dictionary of lists from a list.

In this example, I take the mod (or any other function) of each item as the key. If the key doesn't exist in the dictionary, a new list is created and the item is appended to the list, otherwise the item is directly appended.

```
def get_key(val):
    return val % 3 # Can be something else, it doesn't matter


dict = {}
data = [i for i in range(10)]
for item in data:
    key = get_key(item)
    if key in dict:
        dict[key].append(item)
    else:
        dict[key] = [item]
print(dict)
```

Expected output

```
{0: [0, 3, 6, 9], 1: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5, 8]}
```

To simplify the above code, I have tried this ugly approach:

```
for item in data:
    key = get_key(item)
    dict[key] = [item] if key not in dict else (dict[key], dict[key].append(item))[0]
```

However, how to achieve the same thing without the for-loop, using **list/dict comprehension as a single expression**?

I could think of something like this, but it's not able to append value into a pre-existing list.

```
{get_key(item):[item] for item in data}
```

Related posts:

- [Create a dictionary with list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension)
- [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension) (Note: I'm thinking perhaps conditional expressions might work, but not sure how to combine it with the expession)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of list of the values, with the first element of each sublist being the key which is `[n] +`, then use that to create a dictionary.

```
m = [[n] + [i[1] for i in [(x%3,x) for x in range(10)]if i[0] == n] for n in range(3)]

dictt = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in m}
print(dictt)

>>> {0: [0, 3, 6, 9], 1: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5, 8]}
```

All on one line

```
dictt = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in [[n] + [i[1] for i in [(x%3,x) for x in range(10)]if i[0] == n] for n in range(3)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close. below is my approach for using dict comprehension

```
data = list(range(0,10))
mod= 3
{i:data[i::mod] for i in range(mod)}
```

Out

```
{0: [0, 3, 6, 9], 1: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5, 8]}
```

Comment: Thank you. This method works well for data of a list of increasing consecutive integers in case the key is determined by mod. But it can't be generalized to other cases when the key is determined by other rules. I have updated my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need list/dict comprehension here. Just use a normal loop with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
out = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in range(10):
    out[i % 3].append(i)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Practically it works, but I'm looking for a single expression solution using list/dict comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Try [default dict](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/defaultdict-in-python/),

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in range(10): 
    d[item % 3].append(item)
```