# Python: Check if string in a list of strings does not contains variable

Tags: python, string, variables

I have a list of strings:

`my_list = ["John 123", "Johnny 232", "Jane 344"]`

What I want to do is check if a string in my_list *does not* contain a variable ***exactly***, but anything else in the string after the variable doesn't matter.

For example if I have `var = "John"`, my_list[0] would return True, but both my_list[1] and my_list[2] would return False. I need to check the entire list or until one returns True, whichever comes first.

EDIT: Here's a snippet of the actual code I'm working on:

```
names = []
```

```
rank, male, female = info
 for name in names:
  if male not in names:
   names.append(male + " " + rank + '\n')
  if female not in names:
   names.append(female + " " + rank + '\n')
```

info gets pulled from a html file, but for example will be something like `['123', 'John', 'Jane']`, a number followed by a male name and a female name. My problem as of now is obviously the if statements will always be True, resulting in duplicate entries besides for the number.

Comment: Use word boundaries, e.g. for the first case search for `\bJohn\b`

Comment: Hello! What have you done so far :D you can kindly paste your code.

Comment: Added an actual code snippet

Comment: @StackOffended Code pasted above

Comment: You can check my answer if it satisfies to the solution to your problem :D

Comment: Now you leave us wondering what's in `info`. Please reduce this to a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) easily.
[List comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

```
import re


my_list = ["John 123", "Johnny 232", "Jane 344"]

#Just an output list for you to see the True & False output
outputlist = []


for name in my_list:
    if re.search(r'\bJohn\b',name) != None:
        outputlist.append(True)
    else:
        outputlist.append(False)



'''
#List comprehension
outputlist = [True if re.search(r'\bJohn\b',name) != None else False for name in my_list]
'''

print(outputlist)
```

**Output:**

```
[True, False, False]
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but how do I do the same with a variable instead of hard coding "John"? I'm lousy with regex haha

Comment: you mean a `variable`? containing a specific string? you can just change from the regex like this for example `re.search(r'\b'+variable+'\b',name)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `any()` function for this, along with a list comprehension.

```
if any(var in item for item in my_list)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If var = "John", both "John" and "Johnny" will return true, when only "John" should.

Comment: @IanWaddell Ahh, I overlooked that requirement.  My bad.