# Using list comprehension to apply hashtag to items in list where hashtag is not present

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

I'm attempting to understand and explore how conditionals can be written inside a list comprehension:

I'd like to convert the following for loop, that adds a dot to the first position of a string if a dot is not present, into list comprehension:

```
    dot = ['.hello', 'world']

    for i in range(len(dot)):
        if dot[i][0] != ".":
            dot[i] = "." + dot[i]
```

I've believe that I must have incorrectly applied the format described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension):

```
test = ["." + x for x in dot if dot[x][0] != "."]
```

... and consequently receive the following:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I completely understand that readability is affected - I'm simply attempting list comprehension for my own learning.

Comment: You forgot to use `range` in your list-comprehension version, so you're iterating over each character of the string, rather than indices. This is why you're getting a type error about attempting to index a list with a `str`.

Comment: Equivalent of your `for` loop as *list comprehension* will be: `["." + dot[i] if dot[i][0] != "." else dot[i] for i in range(len(dot))]`. However a better version is already shared as an [answer by PacketLoss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65783195/2063361)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the list from inside a list comprehension - the comprehension expression returns a new list. So instead of thinking about `dot[some_index]`, you should be thinking about the element in the list, `x`, and what you want to do with it:

```
result = ['.' + x if x[0] != '.' else x  for x in dot]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[x if x.startswith('.') else '.' + x for x in dot]
```

Is the correct way to do this in a list comprehension.

You are addressing `dot` incorrectly in your loop.

```
test = ["." + x for x in dot if dot[x][0] != "."]
```

`x` in `dot` is the element in your list, a string. You cannot use `strings` to access an index in a list.