# Comparing NumPy arrays so that NaNs yield NaNs

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
```

---

I have two arrays:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,np.nan,5])
b = np.array([3,2,np.nan,5,4])
```

I would like to compare the elements in these two arrays & get a list of booleans as result. When there is `nan` involved in the comparison, I'd like to get `nan`. Expected result:

```
[False, False, nan, nan, True]
```

---

I have achieved the desired output using an [if-else involving list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension):

```
[eacha>eachb
 if ~np.isnan(eacha) and ~np.isnan(eachb)
 else np.nan
 for eacha, eachb in zip(a,b)]
```

---

Is there a better (ie not involving for loop, if-else statements) way of doing this?

Comment: `np.where(np.isnan(a * b), np.nan, a==b)` should be faster than the given answer since it avoids an unnecessary third operation.  Since `NaN` times anything equals NaN, we can use multiplication rather than an `or` at the end.

Comment: If you only care about truthy vs falsey in your final result, you could speed this up even more with `(a * b) * (a == b)`

Comment: Could you elaborate in this last one? I would like to have True-s and False-s in my array, not floats.

Comment: @zabop if you want `nans` then **you must use a float dtype**

Comment: Why the datatype of the nan has to be imposed over the whole array, why can't I have float nans and boolean Trues Falses?

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
np.where(np.isnan(a)|np.isnan(b), np.nan, a==b)
```

But then you get a float array, since `np.nan` is float:

```
array([ 0.,  1., nan, nan,  0.])
```

Comment: Thank you. If you can suggest a way to make 0.s False and 1.s True, that would be awesome (added such a way, but apparently that's not that great).

Answer (score 1):

To change [Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang)'s [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66497783/8565438)'s output from floats to booleans, we can use [pandas.Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
pd.Series(np.where(np.isnan(a)|np.isnan(b), np.nan, a==b)).replace({0:False,1:True}).to_numpy()
```

resulting in:

```
0    False
1     True
2      NaN
3      NaN
4    False
dtype: object
```

or:

```
pd.Series(np.where(np.isnan(a)|np.isnan(b), np.nan, a==b)).replace({0:False,1:True}).to_numpy()
```

resulting in:

```
array([False, True, nan, nan, False], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is *not* an improvement at all.

Comment: Thank you. Edited this post so now improvement is not mentioned, just that the result is boolean this way, not floats.

Comment: @zabop no, the result id `dtype=object` which is generally just bad. You lose the advantages of `numpy` that way. This is all probably not an improvement over just using regular python lists and loops. A `dtype=object` numpy array is basically a less performant python list. I didn't downvote, btw, but this might explain the general aversion to this answer

Comment: In my case, performace is not an issue. Readability of the dataframes I am creating, is. That is why I need Trues and Falses, not floats. Thank you for the comment, it is useful.