# Invalid Syntax involving Else statement in list comprehension in python 3.8

Tags: python

I am just now learning list comprehension in my python class and would like to know why the below code returns an invalid syntax error as a result of the "else" clause?

```
allDays=["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

daysWithPlaydate=[]

for days in range(len(allDays)):
    answer=input("Is there a playdate on " + allDays[days] + "?")
    if answer == "yes":
        daysWithPlaydate.append(allDays[days])
        
outputs=["Weekday Playdate: " + weekdays for weekdays in daysWithPlaydate if weekdays!="Friday" or weekdays!="Saturday" or weekdays!="Sunday" else "Weekend Playdate: " + weekdays for weekdays in daysWithPlaydate] 
for i in range(len(outputs)):
    print(outputs[i], end=", ")
```

P.S.: For the print statement at the end, I would like to know how to remove the final comma when I print out the list, as I always seem to get a comma after the final day in the list, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

Comment: you can make use of `join()` to achieve the desired format, please see my updated answer as I missed that earlier.

Comment: Hi @conrorket, welcome to Stack Overflow! You could probably split the very long condition up a bit for readability by adding a function - something like `def not_in_weekend(day): return day != "Friday or ...`. Use that in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop twice.

Also, the conditional statement is invalid and should be as:

```
outputs=["Weekday Playdate: " + weekdays if weekdays not in ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"] else "Weekend Playdate: " + weekdays for weekdays in daysWithPlaydate]
```

I have also made use of `in` keyword to further simplify the conditional statements.

To solve the output formatting issue, you can use the `join()` method to print the output as:

```
print(', '.join(outputs))
```

Output:

```
Weekday Playdate: Monday, Weekend Playdate: Saturday, Weekend Playdate: Sunday
```

Answer (score 1):

Valid Santax for list comprehension involve IF-ELSE is :

```
list_ = [statment1_  If cond1_ else statment2_ for i in iterable_]
```

Comment: I tried that but received an invalid syntax error at the "if" statement.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me `[statment1_  (If cond1_ else statment2_) for i in iterable_]` should be `[statment1_ If cond1_ else statment2_ for i in iterable_]` where parentheses should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Krishna's answer should solve your list comprehension problem.

With regard to your question about comma at the end, if you want them in a line separated only by a comma, and no comma at the end, then you could just print the unpacked list, and use the seperator keyword instead of end for the print function. i.e.

```py
print(*outputs, sep=", ")
```