# Python: replacing specific list values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of words as an output,
`data = ['1', '60s', '80s', 'metal', 'garage rock', 'adult alternative pop rock']`.
From this list, I would like to replace specific values with the value 'rock'.
I have list of values that I want to replace with 'rock', namely `rocklist = ['metal', 'garage rock', aldult alternative pop rock']`. I want to delete the other values from the list.

I tried to do the following:

```
replace= ['rock' if x== rocklist else x for x in data]
``'print(replace)'''
```

but this didn't work. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with one list comprehension:

```
data = ['1', '60s', '80s', 'metal', 'garage rock', 'aldult alternative pop rock']
rocklist = ['metal', 'garage rock', 'aldult alternative pop rock']
data_filtered = [ i if i not in rocklist else 'rock' for i in data ]
```

returns :

```
['1', '60s', '80s', 'rock', 'rock', 'rock']
```

Comment: That code leaves the non-rock elements in the list. According to the OP, those should be removed.

Comment: @inof for me it is not clear. I read it as he want to replace them and remove the origial ones. As op did not mention this too in his comment to my answer, I will leave the answer like this.

Comment: Ok … maybe the OP needs to clarify. To me it seemed clear: First “list of values […] to replace”, and then “delete the other values” (quoted from the question). It didn't occur to me that he could have meant it differently, but it’s certainly possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if else` in your list comprehension [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

```
>>> data = ['1', '60s', '80s', 'metal', 'garage rock', 'adult alternative pop rock']
>>> rocklist = ['metal', 'garage rock', 'adult alternative pop rock']
>>> replace = [i if i not in rocklist else 'rock' for i in data]
>>> print(replace)
['1', '60s', '80s', 'rock', 'rock', 'rock']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
replace = ['rock' for x in data if x in rocklist]
```

*Explanation:* It’s a list comprehension that returns a list containing the string "rock" for each element of the list `data` that is contained in the list `rocklist`. In other words, it contains the string "rock" n times, where n is how often an element of rocklist occurs in data.

Note that the other elements (those that are not in `rocklist`) are *not* included in the resulting list, as the OP explained. Otherwise a ternary expression can be used to include those elements (`'rock' if x in rocklist else x`).

Comment: This won't include the "non-rock" elements

Comment: @Throckmorton – That’s what the OP wants, actually: “the other values I want to delete from the list.”

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 – Actually the code should speak for itself. It’s a list comprehension that returns a list containing the string "rock" for each element of the list `data` that is contained in the list `rocklist`. In other words, it contains the string "rock" *n* times, where *n* is how often an element of `rocklist` occurs in `data`. In essence, the result is exactly what the OP described. In particular, note that the OP does *not* want elements to remain that are *not* in `rocklist` (see my other comment above).

Comment: @inof Thanks for the explanation. You may think the code speaks for itself but an answer with an explanation is almost always more valued. See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405939/do-good-answers-require-an-explanation).

Comment: @M-Chen-3 – Thanks for reminding me. You are right. I have added the explanation to the answer, so people don’t have to look through the comments in order to find it.