# how can i use If-else and for loop both in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

suppose I have a list arr, and I want store this list elements by decreasing each element by 3, but if the number become negative after modification it should not be store How can i do that?

```
arr = [1, 5, 8, 10]

expected output>> arr1 =[2,5,7]
```

i am trying it like this using list comprehension but getting syntax error

```
arr1 = [x-3 if x is not < 0 else continue for x in arr]
```

can anyone help me to correct it , how can i do this by list comprehension?

Comment: `x is not < 0` doesn't make any sense. You probably wanted to write `x >= 0`. Also there is no such thing as `else continue` in a list comprehension. Just omit the `else` part. I also suggest you to start by learning Python before you attempt to write code in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr2=[x-3 for x in arr if x-3>0]
```

Output:

```
[2, 5, 7]
```

Comment: I want to ask you 2 things , I have a little doubts, ,  If you can explain a little
1st.  x-3 > 0 (work fine) and x-3 >= 0 (why it will not work)

2nd. x-3 > 0 and x - 3 is not < 0 is it not same ? ( 4 -3 = 1 so 1 is not < 0 , it should store > i think , can you please help me to Understand, I know it may be silly doubts but still i am asking you

Comment: @PallabTewary ```>=``` checks if the difference is **less than or equal to** 0 but ```>``` will check if difference is **greater than** 0

Answer (score 1):

Filters go at the end of the comprehension like this:

```
arr = [x - 3 for x in arr if x - 3 > 0]
```

Comment: should be `x-3>0`

Comment: That won't work. if ```x==1```, then ```x>0``` but ```x-3 = -2```

Comment: Maybe neither of you refreshed the page before my edit?