# Python rounding values not working with Numpy condition produce TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float

Tags: python, rounding, numpy-ndarray

I have situation where numpy condition does not working when rounding some threshold value(22.0) to 0 in array. Second option of numpy condition `rainB[np.where(rainB<threshold)]=0.0` also does not work. The result showed ;`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'`. Anyone got ideas?. Thanks

```
tempA=[183.650,185.050,185.250,188.550]    
rainA=[41.416,16.597,20.212,30.029]    
threshold=22.0
temp_new=[183.110,187.20,184.30,186.0]

rainB=[]
for x in temp_new:
    if x <=185.0:
        rain1 = np.interp(x, tempA, rainA)
    else:
        rain1=0.2*x+0.7
    
    rainB.append(rain1)

    rainB[rainB < threshold] = 0.0
    ##rainB[np.where(rainB<threshold)]=0.0
```

Comment: Here `rainB` is not a numpy array but the regular list.

Comment: thanks @MichaelO. what is this actually? Thought it still an array after append those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `rainB` is a list and not a numpy array, but you are trying to use it with with numpy tools. You can rewrite the whole code using numpy as follows:

```
import numpy as np

tempA = [183.650, 185.050, 185.250, 188.550]
rainA = [41.416, 16.597, 20.212, 30.029]
threshold = 22.0
temp_new = [183.110, 187.20, 184.30, 186.0]

arr = np.array(temp_new)
rainB = np.where(arr <= 185, np.interp(temp_new, tempA, rainA), 0.2 * arr + 0.7)
rainB[rainB < threshold] = 0.0

print(rainB)
```

It gives:

```
[41.416      38.14       29.89289286 37.9       ]
```

Comment: awesome. it works here. it also faster for large data.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension could work here:

```
 rainB = [0 if x < threshold else x for x in rainB]
```

See [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension).

Comment: @njp..thanks alot. it works but I have to twist the sign to > in order to catch the values larger than threshold.

Comment: @Azam. Oops, you are right. I've adjusted the answer.