# Avoiding for loops using list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, list-comprehension

Suppose I have this pandas.Series:

```py
import pandas as pd
returns = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
```

And I want to do some simple mathematics stuff on it and save the results in a new list. So I 'll explain them.
For the first item I want to calculate **Variance** of `returns` items:

```py
import numpy as np
def First(Ser):
    return np.var(Ser)
```

For rest of them I want to do this:

```py
def rest(variances , returns , i):
    return 0.94 * variances[i-1] + ( 1 - 0.94 ) * (returns[i-1])**2
```

Then using list comprehension:

```py
variances = [rest(variances , returns , i) for i in range(len(returns)) if i!=0 else First(returns)]
```

But it gives me this error:

> variances = [rest(variances , returns , i) for i in range(len(returns)) if i!=0 else First(returns)]
> ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How can I avoid using a `for` loop for this purpose?
Full script:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

returns = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])

def First(Ser):
    return np.var(Ser)
    
def rest(variances , returns , i):
    return 0.94 * variances[i-1] + ( 1 - 0.94 ) * (returns[i-1])**2
    
variances = [rest(variances , returns , i) for i in range(len(returns)) if i!=0 else First(returns)]
```

---

### More explaination:

What is `variances`?
`variances` is a list that I want to be built with the List Comprehension technique! I want to use `variances` simultaneously as it is created. **My basic goal** is to avoid using a `for` loop.

**Algorithm & Expected output with use of `for` loop:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

returns = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
variances = []

for item in range(len(returns)):
    if item == 0:
        variances.append(np.var(returns))
    else:
        variances.append(0.94*variances[item-1] + (1-0.94)*(returns[item-1])**2)

print(variances)
```

> [2.0, 1.94, 2.0636, 2.4797840000000004, 3.290996960000001]

Comment: Thank you for posting a good question. It includes a proper problem description, a question, your own code in form of a minimal reproducible example and a description of what errors occur. I wish more people would follow the same pattern.

Comment: What's `variances`

Comment: @U12-Forward its a list that is creating with list comprehension فechnique. `variances = [rest(variances , returns , i) for i in range(len(returns)) if i!=0 else First(returns)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

Comment: @Finomnis thanks. it would be great to vote it up if you found it useful.

Comment: @Finomnis nope!

Comment: @Shayan why not? It answers the question why you get the `invalid syntax` error

Comment: @Shayan I will vote it up if you add the definition of `variances` ;)

Comment: @Finomnis sure, I'll do it in few minutes.

Comment: @Finomnis if you check my code, my statement  after `else` isn't  string! it should be another function!

Comment: @Shayan have you even read the responses to the linked question?
The order of your statements in the list comprehension is wrong, it should be `[f(x) if condition else g(x) for x in sequence]`. I fail to see how the type of the statement would make any difference.

Comment: @Shayan sergiomahi even answered that below. Please don't dismiss comments prematurely.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how list comprehensions work. We could help you if you would post what the expected outcome of your code is supposed to be. Like, if your code would run successfully, what values are supposed to be in `variances` at the end? That would help us in identifying what you are trying to do.

Comment: With your `for` loop example and the expected outcome, I now understand what the goal of your algorithm was. Sadly, I think using the unrolled `for` loop is the correct approach. As the iteration references other items in the output list, it is unsuitable for a list comprehension. If I would have to implement your problem, I would also have used a normal `for` loop.

Comment: @Finomnis just I want to thank you! it's so clear! I don't understand why should you be pessimistic about someone is trying to say thanks for your attention to my problem!

Comment: As a further explanation: List comprehensions are meant for mapping problems where every item can be computed independently from all other items. This is sadly not the case for your problem, and that is why I think list comprehension is the incorrect tool here.

Comment: There could be, but I still think the for loop is the most elegant solution. Why do you want to get rid of it? Like, what's your motivation?

Comment: it's utilizing higher speed! I want to practice **Functional Programing** (that you know isn't easy). I decided to begin with list comprehensions. after that for more speed, using functional programing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to the `i-1`'th element of a list (`variances`) you are creating via list comprehension which I think is not possible. However you could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def rest(variances , returns , i):
    if i == 0:
        variances[i] = np.var(returns)
        return variances [i]
    else:
        variances[i] = 0.94 * variances[i-1] + ( 1 - 0.94 ) * (returns[i-1])**2
        return variances [i]

returns = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
placeholder = np.zeros(len(returns))

variances = [rest(placeholder , returns , i) for i in range(len(returns))]

print(variances)

# [2.0, 1.94, 2.0636, 2.4797840000000004, 3.290996960000001]

print(placeholder)

# [2.         1.94       2.0636     2.479784   3.29099696]
```

You do not necessarily need to return the values in the `rest` function, as the actual purpose of the function is to update the existing `placeholder` list. However, if your function does not return anything, the list comprehension will return a list of `None` values.

Comment: Agree, this is also what came to my mind, if you forcefully want to avoid the for loop. The question is, though, if that is more elegant or easiert to read/maintain than the for loop.

Comment: You technically don't even need the entire placeholder array, you only need a single variable to carry over the [i-1] element, the rest doesn't get reused.

Comment: It is? Oh that must be because of the `.append`. Would you mind checking how fast the for-loop is with a pre-allocated object and direct [i] writes?

Comment: Thanks! it's one of the potential solutions! nice one. Thanks a lot ♥

Comment: I tested this.  The list comprehension is not twice as fast.  It's barely faster, and in some forms slightly slower.  List comprehension is a convenient way of writing an iteration that collects results in a list, but it is not a significant time saver.  Wrapping the action in a function, as done here, is certainly better than performing some convoluted if/else inline.  It shouldn't be confused with array "vectorization" that moves iterations to compiled code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @hpaulj, I did not test the speed properly the first time. Not sure what happened but somehow I messed up the speedtest. I'll delete the comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You are misplacing the if condition:

```
variances = [rest(variances , returns , i) if i!=0 else First(returns)
 for i in range(len(returns)) ]
```

Comment: this gives me : `**NameError**: name 'variances' is not defined`. but I defined variances in `variances = [rest(variances , returns , i) for I in range(len(returns)) if i!=0 else First(returns)]`. I want to use `variances` simultaneously as it is creating!

Comment: You can't use something simultaneous to creating it, that is a misconception. There is a temporal order to things, and if doing an `=` assignment, the right side gets evaluated before it gets written to the left side, so while the list comprehension gets executed, the `variances` variable does not exist yet. What is the expected output of your algorithm?

Comment: @Finomnis Thanks for your explanations! I updated the question with my expected output!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC You could try `np.where`:

```
variances = np.where(returns != 0, rest(variances , returns.tolist(), returns.index), First(returns.tolist()))
```

Comment: Thanks. but unfortunately I didn't got your point exactly. I updated my question and further explanation added as well.