# I'm making a hangman project but can't figure out how this piece of code works

Tags: python

I want to know what `letter if letter` means in this code.

I have no variable that's called like that, so how can this be valid?
And how does this work in general?

```
word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else "-" for letter in word]
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68969401/1405065) in the duplicate question is the one that most clearly spells out what is going on in your code. There's a list comprehension (`[some_expr for some_var in some_sequence]`), and inside of `some_expr`, a ternary expression (`value if condition else other_value`). It can be a bit confusing because list comprehensions can also contain `if` clauses (but not `else`), and because the comprehension and the condition in your ternary both use `in` (for different purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about list comprehensions here:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Your line of code is the exact same as the following piece (*I assume, you have variables named `word` and `used_letters` defined somewhere before*):

```
word_list = []

for letter in word:
    if letter in used_letters:
        word_list.append(letter)
    else:
        word_list.append("-")
```

The first part `letter if letter in used letters else "-"` is just shorthand if-else and the rest is for the list comprehension, so as you would not need to define `letter` in the for loop, which I provided above, the same goes for your line: `letter` variable does not need to be defined before, since it is a for loop variable.

Comment: thank you i understand it completely now!

Answer (score 0):

```
word_list = [letter if  letter in used_letters else "-" for letter in word]
```

Here '**letter** if  letter' is a variable created for the sake of list comprehension ( it works inside the square brackets i.e. **[ ]** and we cannot access the value inside this variable outside this brackets )in python so that we can use this variable to filter out if this **letter** is **in** the `used_letters` list.

Comment: thanks i get it now. But i have one last problem. the code does not replace the dash sith the user_letter how can that be?