# If/Else Statements Inside a List Definition?

Tags: python, arraylist

I've been using Python for a long time, but I've recently discovered a new way of creating and iterating through lists:

```
l = [x for x in range(0, 10)]
```

This produces a list from 0 to 9. It's very useful, and much simpler than what I had been doing before:

```
l = []
for x in range(0, 9):
    l.append(x)
```

Now that I understand this way of doing things, I've been using it for a lot of stuff, and it's working out great. The only problem is, I sometimes want another option. For example, if I have a list full of 1's and 0's:

```
import random

l = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(0, 10)]
```

I want to take this list and iterate through again, only do two different things based on an if else statement:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(l):
    if item == 1:
        l[idx] = 'A'
    else:
        l[idx] = 'B'
```

I know it would be easier to just create a list full of random instances of `'A'` and `'B'`, but this is just an example, it won't work in my use case. How would I use my new way of creating lists to do this? I know how to add an if statement on the end:

```
l = [x for x in range(0, 10)]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
l = [x for x in range(0, 10) if i != 7]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

But what about my else statement? And, incidentally, what is this way of creating lists called? I might have been able to find an answer online if I knew.

Comment: It's called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and there are similar ones for dictionaries and sets. If you try it with a tuple you get a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/), which is something else again.

Comment: `['A' if i == 1 else 'B' for i in l]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called list comprehension and it is very helpful indeed!

This post answers your question: [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

And in your example, you want to do:

```
L = ['A' if random.randint(0, 1)==1 else 'B' for i in range(0, 10)]
```

Comment: There's nothing called `random`. You'll get error for that

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so let's clear some things up. Firstly, **this** way of creating lists is called **list comprehension**.

### Now, let's talk about how to achieve a list of `A's` and `B's`(by list comprehension):

```
import random

# This creates a list of 1's and 0's
l = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(0, 10)]
# [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

# This creates a list of A's and B's
l = ['A' if num == 1 else 'B' for num in l]
#['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
```

### How to do it normally (without list comprehension)?

```
import random

l = []
for x in range(0, 10): # This should be 10 instead of 9 to get 10 values. 
    l.append(random.randint(0,1))
# l = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

for idx, item in enumerate(l): # You need to use `enumerate()` to get index, value
    if item == 1:
        l[idx] = 'A'
    else:
        l[idx] = 'B'
# l = ['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Python's [ternary operator](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html):

```
l = ['A' if i == 1 else 'B' for i in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

The method of creating lists that you used is called a "list generator". Similarly, there is a dictionary generator.

To solve your problem, you need to add conditions inside the list generator:

```
import random

new_list = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(0, 10)]
another_new_list = ['A' if number == 1 else 'B' for number in new_list]
```

Comment: It's called a list comprehension, not a list generator.

Comment: Also, there's no need to create a new list to get A's and B's