# Problems converting a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This list comprehension works, but I’d rather have it written like conventional loops:

Here is the list comprehension:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    x = [[int(num) for num in line.split(',')] for line in f if line.strip() != "" ]
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    x = []
    for line in f:
        for num in line:
            if line.strip() != '':
                x.append((num))
```

What I tried doesn't work. First off, I don't know where to add the split(',') line and I’m not sure where I can get *num* to be integers.

Comment: see [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 2):

It would be more like:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
    x = []
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip():
            # Skip this line
            continue
        inner_list = []
        for num in line.split(","):
            inner_list.append(int(num))
        x.append(inner_list)
```