# Why is this if/else list comprehension not working?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, list-comprehension

i have list with booleans (True, False), strings ('TRUE', 'FALSE) and also 'VOID'

```
x = [True, False, True, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'VOID']
```

i wish to change everything to a bool value aside from 'Void'. I am trying to use the following list comprehension but it breaks on the 'else' part no matter what:

```
c = [bool(z) for z in x if z is True or z is False or z == 'TRUE' or z == 'FALSE' else z for z in x]
```

there are many similar posts eg [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension) which gives the generalisation:

```
[f(x) if condition else g(x) for x in sequence]
```

but its clear that it does not work here. Any one know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the generalization you wrote in the question, your list comprehension should be:

```
c = [bool(z) if z is True or z is False or z == 'TRUE' or z == 'FALSE' else z for z in x]
```

with output

```
[True, False, True, True, True, 'VOID']
```

Comment: perfect that worked, thanks. Had the 'for' loop in twice.