# Batch update validation and formatting cells using pygsheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I am using pygsheets and would like to batch validate cells instead of looping through each cell and doing it iteratively. I have gone through the [pygsheets documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pygsheets/downloads/pdf/stable/) and have not found an example of this, would this be possible and if so how would one do this? I did see an example of batching [in the documentation (through unlinking and then linking again)](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.6/examples.html), but this did not work for me instead no update happened.

Below I have a working example of the code that I am trying to optimise by batching the update.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

```
import pygsheets

spread_sheet_id = "...insert...spreadsheet...id"
spreadsheet_name = "...spreadsheet_name..."
wks_name_or_pos = "...worksheet_name..."

spreadsheet = pygsheets.Spreadsheet(client=service,id=spread_sheet_id)
wksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet('title',wks_name_or_pos)

header_list = ["A","B","C"]

     for index, element in enumerate(header_list):
            cell_string = str(chr(65+index)+"1")
            wksheet.cell(cell_string).set_text_format('bold', True).value = element
            header_cell = wksheet.cell(cell_string)
            header_cell.color = (0.9529412, 0.9529412, 0.9529412, 0) # set background color of this cell as a tuple (red, green, blue, alpha)
            header_cell.update()
            wksheet.set_data_validation(
                start=cell_string,end=cell_string, 
                condition_type='TEXT_CONTAINS',
                condition_values=[element], inputMessage=f"Value must be {element}", strict=True)
```

I have realised I can change the value in the cell by passing it in as a list of lists, but not sure how to batch the validation and batch format the cell.

```
header_list = ["A","B","C"]

list_of_lists = [[col] for col in header_list]

# update values with list of lists (working)
wksheet.update_cells('A1:C1',list_of_lists)

# batch update to bold, change the colour to grey and make sure values fit in cell (increase cell size) ?
# wksheet.add_conditional_formatting(start='A1', end='C1', 
#                                           condition_type='CUSTOM_FORMULA', 
#                                           format={'backgroundColor':{'red':0.5,'green':0.5, 'blue':0.5, 'alpha':0}}, 
#                                            condition_values=['=NOT(ISBLANK(A1))'])

# batch validate multiple cells so that the value is strictly the value provided ?
```

I also tried just unlinking, running the pygsheets commands then linking again as

```
wksheet.unlink()
header_list = ["A","B","C"]

     for index, element in enumerate(header_list):
            cell_string = str(chr(65+index)+"1")
            wksheet.cell(cell_string).set_text_format('bold', True).value = element
            header_cell = wksheet.cell(cell_string)
            header_cell.color = (0.9529412, 0.9529412, 0.9529412, 0) # set background color of this cell as a tuple (red, green, blue, alpha)
            header_cell.update()
            wksheet.set_data_validation(
                start=cell_string,end=cell_string, 
                condition_type='TEXT_CONTAINS',condition_values=[element], inputMessage=f"Value must be {element}", strict=True)

wksheet.link()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Your showing 1st script works fine.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your script and want to achieve your multiple requests by one API call.
- You want to achieve this using pygsheets for python.

In this case, how about using `batch_update` of Sheet API Wrapper as follows?

#### Modified script:

```
header_list = ["A", "B", "C"] # This is from your script.

# I modified the below script.
values = [
    {
        "userEnteredValue": {"stringValue": e},
        "userEnteredFormat": {"textFormat": {"bold": True}},
        "dataValidation": {
            "condition": {"type": "TEXT_CONTAINS", "values": [{"userEnteredValue": e}]},
            "inputMessage": "Value must be " + e,
            "strict": True,
        },
    }
    for e in header_list
]
requests = [
    {
        "updateCells": {
            "range": {
                "sheetId": wksheet.id,
                "startRowIndex": 0,
                "startColumnIndex": 0,
                "endRowIndex": 1,
                "endColumnIndex": 3,
            },
            "rows": [{"values": values}],
            "fields": "userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat,dataValidation",
        }
    }
]
service.sheet.batch_update(spread_sheet_id, requests)
```

- `service` is your client for pygsheets.
- When this script is run, the same result as your 1st script is obtained by one API call.

#### References:

- [Sheet API Wrapper](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sheet_api.html?highlight=batch_update#module-pygsheets.sheet)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> I was looking for a solution with the bolding of the cells in the first row, and grey coloring.

> I was also hoping to be able to pass the formatting in individual methods without writing dictionaries with strings (if possible, I understand this may be the only way).

How about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
class Sample:
    startRange = {}
    values = []
    userEnteredFormat = {"textFormat": {}, "backgroundColor": {}}
    dataValidation = {}

    def setStartCell(self, sheetId, row, col):
        self.startRange = {"sheetId": sheetId, "rowIndex": row, "columnIndex": col}

    def setValues(self, v):
        self.values = v

    def setTextFormat(self, v1, v2):
        self.userEnteredFormat["textFormat"][v1] = v2

    def setBackgroundColor(self, v1):
        self.userEnteredFormat["backgroundColor"] = {
            "red": v1[0],
            "green": v1[1],
            "blue": v1[2],
            "alpha": v1[3],
        }

    def setDataValidation(self, v1, v2):
        self.dataValidation = [v1, v2]

    def create(self):
        values = [
            {
                "userEnteredValue": {"stringValue": e},
                "userEnteredFormat": self.userEnteredFormat,
                "dataValidation": {
                    "condition": {
                        "type": self.dataValidation[0],
                        "values": [{"userEnteredValue": e}],
                    },
                    "inputMessage": self.dataValidation[1].replace("{element}", e),
                    "strict": True,
                },
            }
            for e in self.values
        ]
        return [
            {
                "updateCells": {
                    "start": self.startRange,
                    "rows": [{"values": values}],
                    "fields": "userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat,dataValidation",
                }
            }
        ]

spread_sheet_id = "...insert...spreadsheet...id"
wks_name_or_pos = "...worksheet_name..."
spreadsheet = pygsheets.Spreadsheet(client=service, id=spread_sheet_id)
wksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet("title", wks_name_or_pos)
header_list = ["A", "B", "C"] # This is from your question.

s = Sample()
s.setStartCell(wksheet.id, 0, 0)  # cell "A1" (0, 0) of wksheet.
s.setValues(header_list)
s.setTextFormat("bold", True)
s.setBackgroundColor([0.9529412, 0.9529412, 0.9529412, 0]) # R, G, B, Alpha
s.setDataValidation("TEXT_CONTAINS", "Value must be {element}") # type, inputMessage
service.sheet.batch_update(spread_sheet_id, s.create())
```

- In this sample script, a request body for the batchUpdate method is created by `Sample`. And, the created request body is used with `service.sheet.batch_update` of pygsheets.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike . Maybe I am misunderstanding but the e is assigned before the for loop?

Comment: @user4933 Thank you for replying. About `Maybe I am misunderstanding but the e is assigned before the for loop?`, in this case, `values = [{,,,} for e in header_list]` is the comprehension. [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4260280) and [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914) By this part, your value of `header_list = ["A", "B", "C"]` is used with the batchUpdate method of Sheets API. I thought that in this case, when you want to change the format and data validation, it can be achieved by simple modification. So, I proposed it.

Comment: @user4933 And also, in order to expand `header_list` to the 2-dimensional array, I added one more sample modification. Please confirm it. If my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I was looking for a solution with the bolding of the cells in the first row, and grey coloring.

Comment: I was also hoping to be able to pass the formatting in individual methods without writing dictionaries with strings (if possible, I understand this may be the only way).