# Custom annotation of text in seaborn heatmap

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I want to assign different fontsizes for positive and negative values in the following heatmap plotted using seaborn.

```
    import seaborn as sns  # % matplotlib inline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data = np.array([[0.000000, 0.000000], [-0.231049, 0.000000], [0.231049, 0.000000]])
    data = {0: [0.000000, 0.000000], 1: [2.31049, 0.000000], 2: [-0.231049, 0.000000]}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
    sns.heatmap(
        df, cmap='bwr', vmax=10, vmin=0, annot=True, fmt='f',
        linewidths=0.25, annot_kws={"fontsize": 16}, center=0, square=True
    )
    sns.heatmap(
        df, cmap='bwr', vmax=0, vmin=-10, annot=True, fmt='f',
        linewidths=0.25, annot_kws={"fontsize": 6}, center=0, square=True
    )
    plt.show()
```

I tried to specify the min and max and plot, in two steps but the colors and fonts aren't-displayed right.

Suggestions on how to fix this will be of great help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easier to keep the properties in sync, the code below uses a `for` loop. For the positive part, the dataframe is filtered to only contain the positive values. (Internally, pandas fills in `NaN` for the values that get filtered away, and seaborn leaves those cells blank.)

`vmin` and `vmax` are set to the same values for both the negative and positive part of the loop. That way, the colorbar will show all values. To avoid drawing the colorbar twice, `cbar=False` once.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 11, (12, 12)))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for posneg in ['pos', 'neg']:
    sns.heatmap(
        df[df > 0] if posneg == 'pos' else df[df < 0],
        cmap='bwr', vmin=-10, vmax=10, center=0, annot=True, fmt='.0f',
        annot_kws={"fontsize": 16 if posneg == 'pos' else 8},
        cbar=(posneg != 'pos'), cbar_kws={'ticks': range(-10, 11, 2)},
        linewidths=0.25, square=True, ax=ax
    )
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap with different fonts for pos/neg]

PS: The code above uses `if/else` inside some of the arguments.  Such a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) can be handy when only something short is involved, or in a [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension).

An alternative would be to use a normal `if` test together with variables, e.g.:

```py
for posneg in ['pos', 'neg']:
    if posneg == 'pos':
        df_filtered = df[df > 0]
        fontsize = 16
        fontweight = 'bold'
    else:
        df_filtered = df[df < 0]
        fontsize = 12
        fontweight = 'light'
    sns.heatmap(
        df_filtered,
        cmap='bwr', vmin=-10, vmax=10, center=0, annot=True, fmt='.0f',
        annot_kws={"fontweight": fontweight, "fontsize": fontsize},
        cbar=(posneg != 'pos'), cbar_kws={'ticks': range(-10, 11, 2)},
        linewidths=0.25, square=True, ax=ax
    )
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This works great! Can we change the font weights using annot_kws?

Comment: You mean like `annot_kws={"fontweight": 'bold' if posneg == 'pos' else 'light'}`? No problem.

Comment: If you don't like the `if`s inside the call, or when there are too many options to change, you can also add a normal if-test assigning options to variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please add a small example for that as an edit?